# Android relative layout problem with gravity

Tags: android, layout

How can i put textview with id="naslov" to the center? I also tried with layout_gravity="center" but that doesn't work either.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView   
    android:id="@+id/naslov"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:text="Povzetek"
    android:gravity="center"/>
   <TextView   
    android:id="@+id/aha"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:text="Vseh oddaj:"
       android:layout_below="@id/naslov"/>  
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Attribute gravity have no effect inside a RelativeLayout.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android and Layouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990882/android-and-layouts)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Answer (score 46):

```
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

there is also

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Full list for RelativeLayout attributes is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Also you can tell your TextView to fill_parent and then set gravity=center on it. So it'll center actual text within textView.

Answer (score 6):

#### Supplemental Answer

As a more general answer to this question, `layout_gravity` does not work with the subviews of a `RelativeLayout`. It is for use with a `LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout`. However, the subviews of a `RelativeLayout` can still use `gravity` as usual because this is just how a view arranges its own content.

See the comparison in the following image. The green and blue views are TextViews inside of a `RelativeLayout`.

[image]

The `gravity` works but `layout_gravity` doesn't. See [my fuller answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42153928/3681880) for more details.

**See also**

- [Gravity and layout_gravity on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android/26190050#26190050)
- [Positioning views within a RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html#Position)

Answer (score 0):

Relative Layout does not make use of layout_gravity, however you use gravity values in following ways : center, left , left|center , right|center , right, top, bottom.

```
<!-- below widget displaying text in left center -->
<TextView
           android:id="@+id/song_title"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:text="sample name text"
           android:gravity="left|center"
           android:textSize="15sp" />
```