# What is the difference between gravity and layout_gravity in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gravity

I know we can set the following values to the **`android:gravity`** and  **`android:layout_gravity`** properties:

1. `center`
2. `center_vertical`
3. `center_horizontal`, etc.

But I am confused regarding both of these.

What is the difference between the usage of `android:gravity` and `android:layout_gravity`?

Comment: Easy trick to remember: Take "layout-gravity" as "Lay-outside-gravity"

Comment: center == center_vertical | center_horizontal

Comment: These videos helped me a lot  to understand the difference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxfYeAUd238 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FyAIWLVcTc

Comment: **`ImageView`**'s seem to behave different than **`TextView`**'s.

Answer (score 1462, accepted):

Their names should help you:

- `android:gravity` sets the gravity of the contents (i.e. its subviews) of the `View` it's used on.
- `android:layout_gravity` sets the gravity of the `View` or `Layout` relative to its parent.

And an example is [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/how-to-position-views-properly-in-layouts/).

Comment: Basically, everything with `layout_` defines something that effects the elements outside.

Comment: See, I find this funny, because if I just go off the names, my intuition is the other way around. Every time, I think "layout_gravity" means "the gravity for how this ViewGroup lays out it's contents", and "gravity" is "where this View gravitates to".

Comment: So what happens if the `android:gravity` is set to left and its children's `android:layout_gravity` is set to right? which side will the children align to?

Comment: As @Suragch commented on his answer, layout_gravity only works in LinearLayout and FrameLayout. LinearLayout has constraints to it though.

Comment: @Thupten Very good question. I guess one will prevail (I guess the children's layout_gravity) and the other one is only the default for the prevailing one.

Comment: Good answer but the example is wordy and confusing. The ideal answer would be this + the picture from @suragch's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26190050/620856)

Comment: It hasn't been my experience....for a `TextView` that has no subviews, even if you set `textAlignment` as `center` but don't set `gravity`, the text will not be centred....

Answer (score 610):

[**Inside - Outside**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android/26190050#comment21771743_3482757)

- `gravity` arranges the content *inside* the view.
- `layout_gravity` arranges the view's position *outside* of itself.

Sometimes it helps to see a picture, too. The green and blue are `TextViews` and the other two background colors are `LinearLayouts`.

[image]

## Notes

- The `layout_gravity` does not work for views in a `RelativeLayout`. Use it for views in a `LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout`. See my [supplemental answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42153928/3681880) for more details.
- The view's width (or height) has to be greater than its content. Otherwise `gravity` won't have any effect. Thus, `wrap_content` and `gravity` are meaningless together.
- The view's width (or height) has to be less than the parent. Otherwise `layout_gravity` won't have any effect. Thus, `match_parent` and `layout_gravity` are meaningless together.
- The `layout_gravity=center` looks the same as `layout_gravity=center_horizontal` here because they are in a vertical linear layout. You can't center vertically in this case, so `layout_gravity=center` only centers horizontally.
- This answer only dealt with setting `gravity` and `layout_gravity` on the views within a layout. To see what happens when you set the `gravity` of the of the parent layout itself, check out the [supplemental answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42153928/3681880) that I referred to above. (Summary: `gravity` doesn't work well on a `RelativeLayout` but can be useful with a `LinearLayout`.)

*So remember, **layout**_gravity arranges a view in its **layout**. Gravity arranges the content inside the view.*

## xml

Here is the xml for the above image for your reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#e3e2ad"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="gravity=" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#bcf5b1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="left" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#aacaff"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#bcf5b1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="right" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#aacaff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#d6c6cd"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="layout_gravity=" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#bcf5b1"
            android:text="left" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#aacaff"
            android:text="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="#bcf5b1"
            android:text="right" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#aacaff"
            android:text="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

## Related

- [Difference between a View's Padding and Margin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25520320/3681880)
- [Match_parent vs wrap_content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31145234/3681880)
- [How to set both gravity and layout gravity of a LinearLayout programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086486/how-to-set-both-gravity-and-layout-gravity-of-a-linearlayout-programatically/27086487#27086487)

Comment: it seems more easy after seeing it visually, thanks Suragch.

Answer (score 481):

## The difference

`android:layout_gravity` is the **Outside** gravity of the View. Specifies the direction in which the View should touch its parent's border.

`android:gravity` is the **Inside** gravity of that View. Specifies in which direction its contents should align.

## HTML/CSS Equivalents

*(if you are coming from a web development background)*

```
Android                 | CSS
————————————————————————+————————————
android:layout_gravity  | float
android:gravity         | text-align
```

## Easy trick to help you remember

**Take `layout-gravity` as "Lay-outside-gravity".**

Comment: it makes more sense when you have the web developement background.

Answer (score 43):

**Short Answer:** use `android:gravity` or `setGravity()` to control gravity of all child views of a container; use `android:layout_gravity` or `setLayoutParams()` to control gravity of an individual view in a container.

**Long story:** to control gravity in a linear layout container such as `LinearLayout` or `RadioGroup`, there are two approaches:

1. To control the gravity of ALL child views of a `LinearLayout` container (as you did in your book), use `android:gravity` (not `android:layout_gravity`) in layout XML file or `setGravity()` method in code.
2. To control the gravity of a child view in its container, use `android:layout_gravity` XML attribute. In code, one needs to get the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` of the view and set its gravity. Here is a code example that set a button to bottom in a horizontally oriented container:

   ```
   import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
   import android.view.Gravity;
   ...

   Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MyButtonId);
   // need to cast to LinearLayout.LayoutParams to access the gravity field
   LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams(); 
   params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
   button.setLayoutParams(params);
   ```

For horizontal `LinearLayout` container, the horizontal gravity of its child view is left-aligned one after another and cannot be changed. Setting `android:layout_gravity` to `center_horizontal` has no effect.  The default vertical gravity is center (or center_vertical) and can be changed to top or bottom. Actually the default `layout_gravity` value is `-1` but Android put it center vertically.

To change the horizontal positions of child views in a horizontal linear container, one can use `layout_weight`, margin and padding of the child view.

Similarly, for vertical View Group container, the vertical gravity of its child view is top-aligned one below another and cannot be changed. The default horizontal gravity is center (or `center_horizontal`) and can be changed to left or right.

Actually, a child view such as a button also has `android:gravity` XML attribute and the `setGravity()` method to control its child views -- the text in it. The `Button.setGravity(int)` is linked to this [developer.android.com entry](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setGravity%28int%29).

Answer (score 38):

From what I can gather **layout_gravity** is the gravity of that view inside its parent, and **gravity** is the gravity of the children inside that view.

I think this is right but the best way to find out is to play around.

Answer (score 30):

[image]

Look at the image to be clear about gravity

Answer (score 15):

If we want to set the gravity of content inside a view then we will use **"android:gravity"**, and if we want to set the gravity of this view (as a whole) with in its parent view then we will use **"android:layout_gravity"**.

Answer (score 9):

Just thought I'd add my own explanation here - coming from a background on iOS, this is how I've internalized the two in iOS terms:

**Layout Gravity** affects your position in the superview. **Gravity** affects the position of your subviews within you.

Said another way, **Layout Gravity** positions you yourself while **Gravity** positions your children.

Answer (score 9):

An easy trick to remember this is gravity applies to us inside earth. So, `android:gravity` is for **inside** the view.

Rememeber the **out** in *lay**out**_gravity* which would help you to remember that `android:layout_gravity` would refer to **outside** the view

Answer (score 7):

There is many difference in the `gravity` and `layout-gravity`. I am going to explain my experience about these 2 concepts(**All information i got due to my observation and some websites**).

> Use Of Gravity and Layout-gravity in `FrameLayout` .....

**Note:-**

1. **Gravity** is used inside the **View Content** as some User have answer and it is same for all `ViewGroup Layout`.
2. `Layout-gravity` is used with the parent View as some User have answer.
3. `Gravity and Layout-gravity` is **work more useful** with the `FrameLayout` childs . `We can't use Gravity and Layout-gravity` in FrameLayout's Tag ....
4. We can set Child View any where in the `FrameLayout` using `layout-gravity` .
5. We can use every single value of gravity inside the FrameLayout (eg:- `center_vertical`, `center_horizontal`, `center`,`top`, etc), but it is not possible with other ViewGroup Layouts .
6. `FrameLayout` fully working on `Layout-gravity`.  Example:- If you work on `FrameLayout` then you **don't need to change whole Layout** for adding new View. You just **add View** as last in the `FrameLayout` and give him `Layout-gravity` with value.(**This is adavantages of layout-gravity with FrameLayout**).

> have look on example ......

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:textColor="#264bd1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Center Layout Gravity"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:textColor="#1b64b9"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:text="Bottom Layout Gravity" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:textColor="#d75d1c"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:text="Top Layout Gravity"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:textColor="#d71f1c"
        android:gravity="top|right"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:text="Top Right Layout Gravity"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:textColor="#d71cb2"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Top Left Layout Gravity"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Output:-

[image: g1]

> Use Of Gravity and Layout-gravity in LinearLayout .....

`Gravity` working same as above but here differnce is that we can use Gravity inside the `LinearLayout View` and `RelativeLayout View` which is not possible in `FrameLayout View`.

> LinearLayout with orientation vertical ....

**Note:- Here we can set only 3 values of `layout_gravity` that is (`left` | `right` | `center` (also called `center_horizontal`)).**

> have look on example :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:textColor="#264bd1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Center Layout Gravity \nor \nCenter_Horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="#d75d1c"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Right Layout Gravity"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:textColor="#d71cb2"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Left Layout Gravity"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Output:-

[image: g2]

> LinearLayout with orientation horizontal ....

**Note:- Here we can set also 3 values of `layout_gravity` that is (`top` | `bottom` | `center` (also called `center_vertical`)).**

> have look on example :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:textColor="#264bd1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Bottom \nLayout \nGravity"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="#d75d1c"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Center \nLayout \nGravity"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:textColor="#d71cb2"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Left \nLayout \nGravity"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

output:-

[image: g3]

**Note:- We can't use `layout_gravity` in the `RelativeLayout Views` but we can use `gravity` to set `RelativeLayout` childs to same position....**

Comment: If you set `textColor` white in all `view` then it would be very great. :D

Comment: Are you sure? It will look black and white that's why i used different color for every View.

Answer (score 5):

Something I saw on Sandip's blog that I almost missed, fixed my problem. He said `layout_gravity` DOES NOT WORK WITH `LinearLayout`.

If you're using a `LinearLayout` and the gravity settings are driving you nuts (like me), then switch to something else.

I actually switched to a `RelativeLayout` then used `layout_alignParentLeft` and `layout_alignParentRight` on the 2 contained `TextView`s to get them on one line to go far left and far right.

Answer (score 4):

The basic difference between the two is that-

**android:gravity** is used for child elements of the view.

**android:layout_gravity** is used for this element with respect to parent view.

Answer (score 3):

**`android:gravity`** is used to specify how to place the content of the object within the object itself. In another word, android:gravity is used to specify the gravity of the content of the view.

**`android:layout_gravity`** is an attribution the child can supply to its parent, to specify the gravity the view within its parents.

For more details you can visit

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html

Comment: I think no need of new answer as there are multiple answers already posted and with almost the same contents covered!

Answer (score 3):

**Gravity:** Allow you move the content inside a container. (How sub-views will be placed).

**Important:** (MOVE along X-axis or Y-axis within available space).

**Example:** Let's say if you were to work with LinearLayout (Height: match_parent, Width: match_parent) as root level element, then you will have full frame space available; and the child views says 2 TextViews (Height: wrap_content, Width: wrap_content) inside the LinearLayout can be moved around along x/y axis using corresponding values for gravity on parent.

**Layout_Gravity:** Allow you to override the parent gravity behavior ONLY along x-axis.

**Important:** (MOVE[override] along X-axis within available space).

**Example:** If you keep in mind the previous example, we know gravity enabled us to move along x/y axis, i.e; the place TextViews inside LinearLayout. Let's just say LinearLayout specifies gravity: center; meaning every TextView needs to be center both vertically and horizontally. Now if we want one of the TextView to go left/right,  we can override the specified gravity behavior using layout_gravity on the TextView.

**Bonus:** if you dig deeper, you will find out that text within the TextView act as sub-view; so if you apply the gravity on TextView, the text inside the TextView will move around. (the entire concept apply here too)

Answer (score 1):

Gravity is used to set text alignment in views but layout_gravity is use to set views it self. Lets take an example if you want to align text written in editText then use gravity and you want align this editText or any button or any view then use layout_gravity, So its very simple.

Answer (score 1):

**gravity**: is used for simple views like textview, edittext etc.

**layout_gravity**: is used for current view only gravity in context of it's relative parent view like linear Layout or FrameLayout to make view in center or any other gravity of its parent.

Comment: layout_gravity: is used for current view only gravity in context of it's relative parent, not other views which is inside of it's parent.

Answer (score 1):

The `android:gravity` sets the gravity (position) of the children whereas the `android:layout_gravity` sets the position of the view itself. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

**android:gravity** handles the alignment of its children, it sets the gravity of the content of the View it’s used on. In other words it just focuses on the centering of all child views in the parent view. So it works better on a parent view.

**android:layout_gravity** handles the alignment of itself, it sets the gravity of the View or Layout relative to its parent. In other words it focuses on centering a specific child view in the parent view. So it works better on the child view you want centralized.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:gravity
```

is used to adjust for content of the view relative to its specify position (allocated area). `android:gravity="left"`  would not do anything if `layout_width` is equal to the `"wrap_content"`

```
android:layout_gravity
```

is used for view itself relative to the parent or layout file.

Answer (score 0):

`android:gravity` -> Sets the gravity of the content of the View its used on.

`android:layout_gravity` -> Sets the gravity of it's Parent's view or Layout

Answer (score 0):

gravity--Applies to its own view.

layout-gravity---Applies to view related to its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Gravity and layout_gravity both are the XML attributes.

The **android:gravity attribute** is used to arrange the position of the content inside a view (for example text inside a Button widget).

The **android:layout_gravity** is used to arrange the position of the entire View relative to it’s container.

For further details you can see this [link](https://learntodroid.com/what-is-the-difference-between-gravity-and-layout_gravity-in-android/).