# using Framelayout for making panel

Tags: android

Hello i am using following xml to create some sort of Transparent panel . The problem i am facing is that the background image `ac` zoom up , i mean its height get increase , the other thing i would like to know how can i bring this frame in the middle and adjust its width . I have followed [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html) example

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ac" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"

        android:padding="12dip"

        android:background="#AA000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"

        android:text="test test test" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your ImageView have a look at [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Try:

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

If you want to center your Views have a look at [Layout Gravity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity)