# Android: Move Button Text to bottom

Tags: android, xml, text, button

Currently I'm creating a button with Image and Text. My problem is I want to move the text to teh buttom of the button.

```
<Button
  android:layout_weight=".30" 
  android:layout_margin="2dp" 
  android:background="@drawable/btnforgot" 
  android:layout_height="60dp" 
  android:layout_width="100dp" 
  android:text="Forgot "/>
```

Hope someone can help me out in this regard. Searched many places but couldn't come up with a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Simply add `android:gravity="bottom|center"` to your `Button` declaration. If you want to lift it from the bottom slightly, then add `android:paddingBottom="4dp"` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but **`android:gravity="bottom"`** can be helpful to you. Try this inside the `<Button>`.

### Update:

If you want to know about android:gravity and android:layout_gravity then just check this SO question: [Gravity and layout_gravity on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity)

Answer (score 0):

try **android:layout_gravity="bottom"** and **android:gravity="bottom"** properties....it will work.

Comment: android:layout_gravity sets the gravity of the View or Layout in its parent. For more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity/3482757#3482757

Comment: oh yeah rite.. a bit confused between both.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
android:layout_weight="0"
```

It works for me.