# How to center layout inside of Android Dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, customdialog

I am trying to create a custom Dialog, and have its content centered, but it is always ending up left-aligned.  Here is aboutdialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  a:orientation="vertical"
  a:id="@+id/AboutDialogLayout" 
  a:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  a:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  a:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
  a:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageView a:id="@+id/imageView1" 
               a:src="@drawable/pricebook" 
               a:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               a:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView a:layout_height="wrap_content"         
              a:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
              a:id="@+id/textView1" 
              a:text="Price Book" 
              a:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView a:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              a:id="@+id/textView2" 
              a:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              a:text="foo"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my (relevant) code:

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
d.setContentView(R.layout.aboutdialog);
d.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
```

What am I missing here?  Thanks for the assistance.

Image:
[image: Screen shot of Dialog problem]

Comment: That's weird. It works fine for me. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: +1 for using a: instead of android: everywhere, how did you do that?

Comment: Yes, I too check it its working fine.

Comment: @suri: Thats just the namespace prefix

Comment: @suri: Just do a find/replace in the XML for android/a.  Eclipse GUI tools will honor that if changes are made after that.

Comment: @Breakpoint means I can't get it.

Comment: One other data point: This code does work for me on my Android 2.1 (v7) emulator.  The problem is on my Droid X, running 2.3.3.

Comment: holy balls I didn't know you could use a:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try to edit to this: `a:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"` 
**OR** 
use Relative_Layout and align linear layout to center of parent with `fill_parent` for Relative `wrap_content` for Linear.

*although it is worked with me on center*

Comment: Wrapping the whole XML in a RelativeLayout did it.  The `layout_width`s for both *Layouts needs to be `fill_parent` and both `layout_height`s need to be set to `wrap_content` (at least that's how I want it).

Comment: But the problem is child ViewGroup in RelativeLayout must have layout_width=fill_parent to make it work and sometime's you don't want that behavior for your content. See my solution below ;)

Comment: none of this worked out for me ... any other solution?

Comment: I tried `LinearLayout` + `wrap_content` (both gravities were `center`) but it didn't work, so I think `RelativeLayout` is indeed the key: Use `match_parent` (replaced `fill_parent`) for both the `layout_width` and the `layout_height` and set `layout_gravity` and `gravity` to `center`.

Answer (score 2):

Modify Dialog's ViewGroup (FrameLayout) which holds your content layout. I use static method and invoke it inside onActivityCreated() in DialogFragments:

```
/**
 * Center dialog content inside available space
 * @param dialog
 */
public static void centerDialogContent(Dialog dialog) {
ViewGroup decorView = (ViewGroup) dialog.getWindow().getDecorView();
View content = decorView.getChildAt(0);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams contentParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)content.getLayoutParams();
contentParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
content.setLayoutParams(contentParams);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing layout_gravity which is good, but since you do it to the outmost layout, it can't  position itself relative to what's around it.

I think that wrapping the above layout inside another layout would do it

Comment: Wrapping the above XML in another LinearLayout doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing your LinearLayout layout_gravity to just gravity?  See the difference explained here: [Gravity and layout_gravity on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity)

Comment: How about setting a:layout_gravity="center" on each view inside your LinearLayout?