# right align EditText - can't get it to align right with any attribute

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried everything I could possibly find to right align this EditText element - but it won't.

What am I missing here? As you can see I tried both  `android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"` and `android:layout_gravity="right"` without any luck.

ps. the linearLayout is just one element in a parent with RelativeLayout, but I guess that doesn't matter.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/block1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:paddingLeft = "4sp"
  android:padding = "4sp"
  android:layout_height="25sp"
  android:layout_marginTop = "4sp"
  android:layout_below="@+id/Settings_phoneNumbersLbl" 
  android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/Settings_phoneNumbersT1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Settings_phoneNumbersT1"
    />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/myRightAlignedText"
        android:layout_width="170sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you are using the orientation as horizontal. which appends the child views one after another. so i advice you to use RelativeLayout and use layout_alignParentRight, it will work.  or add a empty view in the middle with weight 1.

Comment: you want to align the edittext to right or the contents of edittext to right?????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/block1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:paddingLeft = "4sp"
  android:padding = "4sp"
  android:layout_height="25sp"
  android:layout_marginTop = "4sp"
  android:layout_below="@+id/Settings_phoneNumbersLbl" 
  android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/Settings_phoneNumbersT1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Settings_phoneNumbersT1"
    />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/myRightAlignedText"
        android:layout_width="170sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ..but then the height of the EditText shrinks. So I have to set the height to a fixed size - wrap_content will make it very thin...

Comment: you set the height into the RelativeLayout, just set wrap_content/fill_parent instead of fixed size for height

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
android:gravity="right"
```

This is different from

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

The former affects positioning of content within the View, i.e. the text. The latter affects the View's position inside its parent. See [Gravity and layout_gravity on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity) for a full explanation.

**EDIT**

To align the `EditText` to the right of its parent, try changing the parent to be a `RelativeLayout` rather than a `LinearLayout`, so the `layout_alignParentRight` attribute can take effect.

Comment: I should have mentioned it... this right aligns the text within the EditText, but I need to right align the complete box.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

because

```
android:gravity ="right"
```

means you are setting the children of the view (EditText here - that means text alignment) as right-aligned. To align the EditText itself, use the first one.

Answer (score 1):

> As per LinearLayout property the child elements are always align one
>   after another either its horizontally or vertically,

If you want to put the child element here in right side of parent then I think You should use `FrameLayout`.

or just use `RelativeLayout` and put the both child as per the respected to one-another.

Thanks.