# how to place a view bottom and center of the page android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

i am using a layout and want to display the view at the center and bottom of the page. am using the following code but it stays at the bottom left not center when displayed on tablet. how to make it center.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/ll_bookmarkslistad" android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - gravity and layout_gravity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you need to do is to have this LinearLayout of yours put inside a RelativeLayout. The relative layout is preferably your root layout with `fill_parent` for height as it must reach the bottom.

then add this to your LinearLayout instead of the gravity:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/black"
            android:id="@+id/ll_bookmarkslistad" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >
            <!-- stuff inside layout -->
         </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This seems to put my stuff at the very bottom, no matter what. Margin/padding is being ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `RelativeLayout` with `android:layout_alignParentBottom` and `android:layout_centerHorizontal`

Answer (score 1):

@pink_candy don't use any gravity in LinearLayout, if you are using it,It will be applicable for all child views in that LinearLayout.
If you want any particular view to be aligned, then set layout_gravity parameter to that view only, view can be button, image ,customview or even another layout also.