# RelativeLayout gravity center not working

Tags: android, center, android-relativelayout, gravity

I'm trying to horizontally center several views in a `RelativeLayout` that is a base.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
```

This isn't working. I have set `centerInParent` to `true` for one of the views and that did work. However, I can't use this solution because I have 2 views side by side that need to be centered together. Trying to optimize this so I want to avoid nesting layouts, especially Linear, inside of each other.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing? I thought this attribute is made for this situation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I answered a similar issue involving three views without using nested ViewGroups.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13279846/1011746

This is tested in API 11.

For the two view horizontal case:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:background="@android:color/black"
  >
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/apply"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="APPLY"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    />
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/undo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="UNDO"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/apply"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

For the two view vertical case:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:background="@android:color/black"
  >
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/apply"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="APPLY"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    />
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/undo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="UNDO"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_below="@id/apply"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This solution only works when the views can be stacked in a single line, if the layout is more complex, the only solution is to use nested layouts as the other answers suggest or take a different apprach.

Comment: @mindriot using _For the two view horizontal case:_ does not perfectly center align both the views as it would when using a nested linear layout with orientation set to horizontal and gravity center

Answer (score 10):

You'll need to nest several layouts together. To center something in a RelativeLayout, you use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` on the child. If you try to center several childs, they'll end up under/over each other.

Therefore, for example, you could use a LinearLayout with two views as a child to the RelativeLayout, with the LinearLayout having `android:orientation="horizontal"` and `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`. The LinearLayout should now be centered in the RelativeLayout, with the two children next to each other.

Comment: I'm really trying to optimize this screen since it's the main activity. Therefor I'm really really trying to avoid nesting LinearLayouts. I actually removing all the linearlayouts from this apps since they are terrible inefficient.

Comment: Well, there's no way to do it (good looking) if you cannot nest layouts. At least as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the two views in a LinearLayout and then center the LinearLayout in the RelativeLayout like you did for the single TextView.

Comment: Don't want to nest. And that still doesn't explain the issue that centerInParent works when set to true, but is not working when gravity is set to center_horizontal

Comment: Try `android:layout_gravity="center horizontal"` on your text views.

Comment: No. Thanks for the reply, but that isn't going to work. I need two buttons to be side-by-side so center_horizontal for each will put them on top of each other.

Comment: Then you need to nest layouts.  There is no performance hit to that unless you try to nest views using layout_weight.

Comment: Actually, you can center in parent and then manipulate the position using margins and the align the other textview to that one if you are determined not to nest layouts.

Answer (score 1):

So my fix for this issue turn out just to leverage the compound drawable feature of textview. I just trashed the button and used drawableRight to show the search icon.