# How to center two views within a relative layout?

Tags: android, alignment, android-relativelayout, center

The task is simple: there are two buttons and a `TextView` above them. All the widgets shoud be centered within the relative layout. The only one idea I have is create the third widget `View` and use it as a center axis for the buttons. Any ideas? A redundant layout isn't a good solution.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_axis"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_progress"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_progress"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/view_axis"
        android:text="@string/start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_stop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_progress"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view_axis"
        android:text="@string/stop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Look here, this answers the question, the ticked answer is not what was initially asked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904864/relativelayout-gravity-center-not-working/13280255#13280255

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, you can put the `Button`s in a `LinearLayout` and center that

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_progress">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/start" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_stop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/stop" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

I'm not sure if that's what you meant by a "redundant layout" but doing this is fine if it gives you what you want.

Comment: sure, I can. But it's a redundant `LinearLayout`. After I had read [Android layout tricks #3](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html) and [Android layout tricks #1](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html), I began building layouts more carefully.

Comment: Using it in this way isn't going to hurt you. Maybe if its in a `ListView` but if not this isn't a problem. You don't want too many unnecessary nested `layouts` but in this case it is the easiest way I see to do it. So it isn't unnecessary and there is only one nested `layout`

Comment: thanks! I agree, the nested `LinearLayout` is OK in this case.

Answer (score 7):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp_rooms"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/space"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_registration"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/space"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will vertically and horizontally center the whole block consisting of the textview + buttons

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_start"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/start" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_stop"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/stop" />      

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You are adding an unnecessary `LinearLayout` this way

Comment: How would you center the whole block? With your way the Textview will be centered and the buttons will appear below them.

Comment: The `Button`s will appear centered below the `TextView` which is centered. I think this is what the OP is going for but could be wrong. I haven't had a chance to compare the two `layout`s yet but they should have the same effect

Comment: Sure, horizontally. I posted a solution if they want the whole block (textview and buttons) centered horizontally and vertically. With your method the vertical "weighting" will be off if you see what I mean. Visually it will be heavier in the bottom half of the screen than the top as the textview will hit the center vertical spot and the buttons will appear below it.

Comment: Touche, my friend :) I guess it depends on exactly what exactly is wanted