# Android: Text in the TextView

Tags: android

I set `android:gravity="center"` in TextView for the text in it.And now I wanna get the paddingLeft value of the text.How can I achieve this??? 
Thanks in advance.
**PS:**
I did not set any padding attribute in TextView, except "center".

Comment: Do you get any info using getPaddingLeft()?

Comment: nope.So can you help me to get the width between the left edge and the content's left edge?

Comment: Did it help? The code in the comment below?

Comment: yeah,Ive tried that code and it worked well.But not very accurate I think.   :)

Comment: ok so I am adding that as edit to the post. Might help someone, or someone could suggest something better in that line.

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:layout_gravity` instead of `android:gravity` 
Alse check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity) issue.

Comment: Thx all the same, but I wanna the text center in the TextView ,So I used android:gravity="center".

Answer (score 0):

set it as below:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"              //your desired value
```

Comment: But I wanna get the padding left value of the content in the TextView.

Comment: what do you mean? please elaborate a little more

Comment: I mean I didnt set android:paddingLeft="5dp" ,I just set android:gravity="center"; So that the content aligns center in the TextView. But you know it has some space between the TextView's left and the content's left edge.I wanna get the width of the "space".

Comment: then i believe it might be **Margin**. Paste your layout xml for better help

Answer (score 0):

Try and use getPaddingLeft() but I am not sure whether it will return any value since you are not setting any padding. I don't think setting the gravity actually effects the padding.

**UPDATE**

This would be a hack to do it and a little inaccurate. (I'll see if I can improve it)

```
int txtSize = txt.getTextSize(); 
int count = txt.getText().toString().length(); 
int txtWidth = txtSize*count; 
int padding = txt.getWidth()/2 - txtWidth/2;
```

Comment: yeah, nothing returned.So how can I get the width between the left edge and the content's left edge?

Comment: I saw one more function called getTotalPaddingLeft() but I think its gonna return the same result.

Comment: Try this, Its a long shot. but what the hell. int txtSize = txt.getTextSize(); int count = txt.getText().toString().length(); int txtWidth = txtSize*count; int padding = txt.getWidth()/2 - txtWidth/2;