# GridView filling parent despite wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a gridlayout like this in the main layout xml of my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_gravity="right">

    <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#AAAAAA"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="none"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I populate it with 6 icons by inflating the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/searchIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/searchIcon"/>
```

What I want is that the gridlayout is right aligned in the linear layout and that it just wraps its content. I am testing this by giving it a different coloured background. The layout_height="wrap_content" works fine, but the width seems to have no effect. The result is this:

[image: Screenshot of wrap_content not working as I expect]

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Stephen

Answer (score 0):

use `android:gravity="right"` in LinearLayout instead-of LinearLayout ..............

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"

    android:gravity="right"> //<-----------------------
```

- android:gravity sets the gravity of the content of the View its used
  on.
- android:layout_gravity sets the gravity of the View or Layout in its
  parent.

for test try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/parentLayout"

    android:gravity="right">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/gridview" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#AAAAAA"
        android:text="ewewqe" />

</LinearLayout>
```

also see this not the answer but see

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right" android:weightSum="1">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="#AAAAAA"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="none"
        android:layout_weight=".5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Last two lines are from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3482757/379693) :)

Comment: yes these are just to make the thing clear .....answer is above that... I confirmed because after seeing your answer I was in doubt...... as you set android:gravity="right" in GridView

Comment: Makes no difference. The right align is one part, but I am more concerned about getting the GridView to actually wrap the contents width.

Comment: please make it clear first, so now grid goes to right or not?

Comment: I tried the same code for Textview instead of grid and that is working

Comment: I am sure it works for you with a textview, but it doesn't help me with the GridView unfortunately.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12943/discussion-between-steprobe-and-dheeresh-singh)

Comment: ohh please update   android:layout_weight=".5"  in new sample code

Comment: My question was how to wrap the content in the grid view, not how to get it to take 50% of the screen.

Comment: I know that, I already said that this in not a solution.... but looks width should be there other wise it will take parent width

Answer (score 0):

Insert `android:gravity="right"` in GridView

```
<GridView 
  ......
  .....
  android:gravity="right" />
```

Comment: I tried various combinations of gravity and none of them worked. The problem seems to be that the width of the content, from the perspective of the LinearLayout is full screen.