# layout_gravity not working

Tags: android, layout, layout-gravity

Why my `TextView` doesn't go right?

**Update:** Well, now I don't just need to set `TextView` to the right. Now it is very interesting why `layout_gravity` doesn't work as expected, namely - set the `View` to the position inside it parent container.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
              style="@style/activated_item"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/star"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        style="?android:attr/starStyle"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" //////// HERE I AM 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/item_text_color"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where you want to set textview at extream right of linearlayout? can u just explain that

Comment: @SUmant, yes, I want to set textview to the very right.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to use [`gravity`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:gravity) instead of `layout_gravity`.

Comment: True. But (!) isn't the gravity for components inside layout, and layout_gravity for the View itself? That's the reason I'm confused.

Comment: @siik Yep, that is correct! Your TextView's width matches its parent (you specified it!), and therefore there is no sense in setting a `layout_gravity`. Set the `android:background` to a random color to see how large your TextView actually is. Alternatively, set `android:layout_width` to `wrap_content`, then it'll work with `layout_gravity".

Comment: I just set layout_width to wrap_content and changed it back to layout_gravity="right" and this doens't work.

Comment: @siik Your LinearLayout's orientation is horizontal. Make it vertical. And yes, the layout_gravity thing won't work, because you are using a LinearLayout. Use a RelativeLayout if you want to use the `wrap_content`. Otherwise stick with `android:gravity`.

Answer (score 7):

I have found 2 solutions to that:

1. Set `android:orientation="vertical"`.
2. Use `FrameLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` as the parent for your text/checkbox widgets. It is not primary usage of `FrameLayout` but that advice is also noted in Android documentation:

   > ... You can, however, add multiple children to a
   >   FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by
   >   assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity
   >   attribute.

Comment: But is a FrameLayout can always be interchangeably used with LinearLayout ?

Answer (score 7):

Because you set `orientation` to horizontal, which means you cannot manually change horizontal position of your child views.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
          style="@style/activated_item"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/star"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    style="?android:attr/starStyle"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:gravity="right" //////// HERE I AM 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/item_text_color"/>
```

Comment: gravity applies inside to the view & layout_gravity applies inside the container . I hope your problem is solved? :)

Comment: @siik just check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity    http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/how-to-position-views-properly-in-layouts/

Comment: Please don't say "try this" and post the code with your slight modification. Just tell what needs to be changed. Otherwise, one has to go through every line and compare with the original to find out what you did.

Answer (score 0):

you could use weight also try this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/star"
    style="?android:attr/starStyle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:text="TEST"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the gravity is just to center the text ,what makes it go right is the weight

Comment: Thanks, but I'm more interested why 'layout_gravity' does not work as expected.

Comment: http://sandipchitale.blogspot.co.il/2010/05/linearlayout-gravity-and-layoutgravity.html read here