# What is exact difference between gravity and layout_gravity

Tags: android, xml, gravity, layout-gravity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - gravity and layout_gravity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity)

I have been working on android xml's. I have used `android:layout_gravity="center"` to align components in specific position.

Now a days, when I was working on a **Dialog like Activity**, I came across `android:gravity="center"`. What I found there was, `gravity` was used to align its `child` to a specific position.

I would share an example of what it is,

### android:gravity="center"

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/enterNumberEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:hint="Enter No." >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
            </LinearLayout>
```

It aligns the child of `LinearLayout` in center.

### android:layout_gravity="center"

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_background" >
</LinearLayout>
```

It aligns the `LinearLayout` itself in center.

**Now my questions are:**

1. If I am right in these assumptions, that whether `gravity` is for child components and `layout_gravity` is for parent component.
2. When to choose `gravity` over `layout_gravity`.

I have found this much explanation working on xml's so far. I would like to hear much better explanation of it. Let me know, if I am wrong somewhere

Comment: `gravity` aligns the content of a view, `layout_gravity` aligns a view within its parent.

Comment: These videos helped me a lot to understand the difference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxfYeAUd238

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Yes, your understanding is correct. Any `layout_` attribute gives instructions to the parent view.
2. Generally, if a view is taking up the full width/height of its' parent, then you won't need to specify `layout_gravity`, you'll probably find `gravity` more useful. If your view does not take up an entire dimension of its' parent, you might want to align it depending on your desired look.

Answer (score 4):

Their name should help you :
`android:gravity` sets the gravity of the content of the `View` its used on.
`android:layout_gravity` sets the gravity of the `View` or `Layout` in its parent.

For more info visit [this site](http://sandipchitale.blogspot.in/2010/05/linearlayout-gravity-and-layoutgravity.html)

Answer (score 1):

android:gravity sets the gravity of the content of the View its used on.

android:layout_gravity sets the gravity of the View or Layout in its parent.