# How to put one buttom right and another left

Tags: java, android

I try to create dynamically linerlayout and i created two buttoms.

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        TextView titleView = new TextView(this);
        titleView.setWidth(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        titleView.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        titleView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        titleView.setText("Hallo Welt!");
        layout.addView(titleView);

        Button btnConnect = new Button(this);
        btnConnect.setText("Connect");
        layout.addView(btnConnect);

        Button btnDisconnect = new Button(this);
        btnDisconnect.setText("Disconnect");
        layout.addView(btnDisconnect);
```

I want to put Connect button to left corner and want to put disconnet button to the right corner. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to set layout gravity for your buttons?

```
LayoutParams params;

Button btnConnect = new Button(this);
params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.Left;
btnConnect.setLayoutParams(params);
...
Button btnDisconnect = new Button(this);
params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.Right;
btnConnect.setLayoutParams(params);
...
```

Layout gravity defines where to place a view in its parent (see [Gravity and layout_gravity on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity) too)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use RelativeLayout instead of linear layout.

and add rules to the layout params of the 
    RelativeLayout.Layoutparams params =      `RelativeLayout.Layoutparams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);`