# Button in ActionBarSherlock not vertically centered

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I met a problem in device below Android 4.0, the button in the ActionBarSherlock sometimes just can't vertically centered. This happened on devices running Android 2.3.6, and will not affect on any device running 4.0+

I made a pretty easy custom layout on the ActionBarSherlock, whose custom layout structure is shown in the XML below

### The layout that can't center button vertically:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_action_next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/people_app_theme_color"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="NEXT"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_action_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/people_app_theme_color"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxHeight="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/android_home"
        android:text="HOME"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_action_prev"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/people_app_theme_color"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="PREV"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

And I simply just can't get the buttons (`button_action_next` and `button_action_prev` centered vertically within the action bar)

I got the result like this:

[image]

**However**, in the same app, I have another custom layout for ActionBarSherlock which could strangely make the buttons centered vertically very well. The layout of this custom layout is like this:

### The layout that can center buttons vertically:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_actionbar_done"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/people_app_theme_color"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="DONE"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_actionbar_skip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/people_app_theme_color"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="SKIP"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_actionbar_skip"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_actionbar_skip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="ENTER YOUR DETAILS"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

The only difference between the working layout and not working layout, is the one that can't center buttons has a child `LinearLayout` within it.

So my question is, how can I make sure that the buttons are vertically centered in any circumstances(avoid the result shown in the screenshot)?

## UPDATE: what I've tried

Thanks to @nicopico 's comment and this SO post: [Gravity and layout_gravity on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity) . I've applied `layout_gravity="center"` to my layout, but the buttons are still not vertically centered.

Comment: You are using `android:gravity` instead of `android:layout_gravity` in your `TextView`. There is a *subtle* difference ;)

Comment: @nicopico Hi, I checked this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity and applied `android:layout_gravity` in my buttons that needed to be vertically centered, but it seemed not working for me. Is there any other stuff I need to pay attention to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got the problem.

Here's the solutions

## Solution 1

within this layout,

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_actionbar_done"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/people_app_theme_color"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="DONE"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_actionbar_skip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/people_app_theme_color"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="SKIP"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_actionbar_skip"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_actionbar_skip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="ENTER YOUR DETAILS"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

I deleted

> android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

in the two buttons, and applied:

> android:layout_centerVertical="true"

to both buttons, and it now can vertically centered within the ActionBar

## Solution 2

According to this post [Android ActionBar: How to vertical align views in top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606877/android-actionbar-how-to-vertical-align-views-in-top?lq=1)

I can apply the `android:layout_marginBottom` or `android:paddingBottom` to the buttons to make it centered.

---

However I still prefer the `android:layout_centerVertical` method which is not hard-coded to numbers.