# Android table xml not centered and partially off screen to the left

Tags: android, android-xml

I am trying to organize some data in a table in android but I seem to not be able to figure out how to center the whole entire table:

my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:padding="5dip"
        >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"/>

    <TableLayout  

    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"  
    android:stretchColumns="*"> 

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableStatTitles"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/abvTitle"
            android:text="ABV"
            android:textStyle = "bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/IBUTitle"
            android:text="IBU"
            android:textStyle = "bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/glassTitle"
            android:text="Glass"
            android:textStyle = "bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>


        </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableStat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/abv"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/IBU"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/glass"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>


        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout> 


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/breweryTitle"
            android:text="Brewery: "
            android:textStyle = "bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBrewery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/styleTitle"
            android:text="Style: "
            android:textStyle = "bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="" />

    </TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerDEscriptionTitle"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Description:"
        android:padding="5dip"
        ></TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerDescription"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:padding="5dip"

        ></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I do not think this should have been downvoted. It is not a mindless question.

Comment: @Rarw thanks, I appreciate that. I really hate it when people down vote and dont even have the guts to say why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is related to the difference between `gravity` and `layout_gravity`. `gravity` only sets the positioning of a view's contents, not where it sits within the parent. Changing the `layout_gravity` on the table instead of the gravity will center it within the parent view. You can [read more about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity)

Comment: changed it, and still off center and partially off screen to the left.

Comment: Is everything slightly off center or just the table? You have 3 nested layouts here - your table, the outer linearlayout, and then the scrollview wrapping the whole thing. You will need to likley adjust the settings on all 3. If that doens't work, put the table in its own seperate linearlayout. I hate adding layout elements, but sometimes seperating it out is the only way you can center it the way you want.

Comment: Just the table is off centered

Comment: I just took the gravity central off of both rows and now its at least all on the screen but the whole table is stilled aligned left

Comment: Ok so you're moving in the right direction. You just need to play around with those settings to get the table centered. If the rows are now on screen, I'd focus on the larger elements, the table itself, linear layout, and scrollview.

Comment: ok now I added android:gravity="center" to the text views in the table and they are centered and working! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` in scroll View