# centerHorizontal RelativeLayout in ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I'd like to centerHorizontal a RelativeLayout within a ScrollView like this:
[image: good layout]

I can only achieve this layout when using RelativeLayout. But since I need to use ScrollView aswell, it messes up. Somehow `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` won't apply for RelativeLayout then... Output looks like this:

[image: bad layout]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffcc33"
android:paddingLeft="7dp"
android:paddingRight="7dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search_box"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/search_button"
    android:ems="5"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/search_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/search_button" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search_box"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
     >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_lihatoidud"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/lihatoidud"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Lihatoidud"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_kypsetised"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_lihatoidud"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/kypsetised"
        android:text="Küpsetised"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_seenetoidud"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_kypsetised"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/seenetoidud"
        android:text="Seenetoidud"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_juustutoidud"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_seenetoidud"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/juustutoidud"
        android:text="Juustutoidud"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_lisandid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_juustutoidud"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/lisandid"
        android:text="Lisandid"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_supid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/supid"
        android:text="Supid"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_voileivad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_supid"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/voileivad"
        android:text="Võileivad"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_pudrud"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_voileivad"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/pudrud"
        android:text="Pudrud"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_joogid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_pudrud"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/joogid"
        android:text="Joogid"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

The comment wouldnt let me format...

Here is what I would do, change the overall layout to a linear layout, that way you can make sure that they editText and button are on top. It would look something like this...

```
<LinearLayout
    ...android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
         ...android:orentation="horizontal">
         <Edit Text>
         <Button>
     />
     <ScrollView
        ...>
        <RelativeLayout
             ..../>
     />
/>
```

Comment: Your method had the same problem. I eventually ended up adding one LinearLayout between ScrollView and RelativeLayout. That worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

A `ScrollView` will collapse its contents down to core size unless told otherwise. Try things:

1. Explicitly lock the sides of the `ScrollView` to the positions in the top `RelativeLayout` using

   ```
   android:layout_below="@id/search_box"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   ```
2. Force the `ScrollView` not to collapse:

   ```
   android:fillViewport="true"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using gravity? Try this:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

inside your RelativeLayout.

```
android:gravity="center"
```

may also work. I always forget which one does which.

Comment: [Difference between android:graivty and android:layout_gravity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3482757/312312)

Comment: Alright, on the one hand layout_gravity fits my needs. On the other hand it stretched out the RelativeLayout, so it hides behind the EditText view. Any ideas?

Comment: Which RelativeLayout did you put the gravity in? I'm not sure but it sounds like you put it in the overall layout and not in the child layout.

Comment: I put it into the one containing buttons.
This is the outcome: http://oi40.tinypic.com/96hv6d.jpg

Comment: Hmmm, that is odd, I'm not entirely sure what happened there. I don't have a ton of experience with relative layouts but can't you set it to be underneath that text view?

Here is what I would do, change the overall layout to a linear layout, that way you can make sure that they editText and button are on top. It would look something like this...