# TextView gravity not updating

Tags: android, eclipse, textview

I have a `TextView` contained in a `HorizontalScrollView`, and I want the text to be centered whenever not scrollable, but when the text is big enough to make its `HorizontalScrollView` container scrollable, I need to change the gravity of the `TextView` to be `Gravity.LEFT`. If I do not do this and keep the gravity centered, the `HorizontalScrollView` will show the text wrong, as in it will cut off most of the text, and there will be empty space at the end if the text remains centered. Here is my current code to handle this:

```
//make horizontal scroll text center and work
final HorizontalScrollView toTextScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView)parentView.findViewById(R.id.horizScroll);

toTextScrollView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top,
                        int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop,
                        int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        //if scrollable, change toNumber layout_gravity to left, else keep it at center
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                         LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        if(canScroll(toTextScrollView))
            params.gravity=Gravity.LEFT;
        else
            params.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;


        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Can scroll: " + canScroll(toTextScrollView), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        toNumber.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

});
```

My function `canScroll()` works properly as it updates in the Toast correctly, so that is not the issue. The issue is that I feel the `TextView` needs to "refresh" once setLayoutParams() is called. This is because when the first number is added to the `TextView` that makes it scrollable, the Toast returns it is now scrollable but the Gravity remains centered and therefore the first part of the number is cut of when scrolling left, like this:

[image]

*However*, whenever the **next** number is added it updates properly, the gravity is set to Gravity.LEFT, and therefore none of the text is cut off in the scroll view. How do I properly update the TextView gravity so it happens instantly? **I have tried adding toNumber.invalidate() and toTextScrollView.invalidate() right after setLayoutParams() but it still won't update on time.**

Here is the `TextView`:

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
     android:id="@+id/horizScroll"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     >

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/toField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/lightblue"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:freezesText="true"/>


</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use

`textview.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setGravity%28int%29

check this too: [Gravity and layout_gravity on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity)

Comment: setGravity is working perfectly for me. Have you tried calling setText again after setLayoutParams?

Comment: The problem is the TextView needs its layout_gravity set to center, not its Gravity, which wouldn't do anything if it is in a HorizontalScrollView as it has to have a width of wrap_content. Sadly setting the text after does nothing.