# Difference between android:layout_gravity and android:gravity

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm some what new to **android** and I'm really confused very much about the difference between parameters **android:layout_gravity** and **android:gravity**. So can someone please help me on using these.
Thank you!

Comment: possible duplictae http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android:layout_gravity` is the gravity related to your whole Layout like LinearLayout,Relative layout and `android:gravity` is the gravity related to your particular view like Button,EditText..etc 
Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

android:gravity sets the gravity of the content of the View its used on.

android:layout_gravity sets the gravity of the View or Layout in its parent.

go through this [example](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/how-to-position-views-properly-in-layouts/)

Answer (score 1):

android:gravity applies graivity to the content of the view, while
android:layout_gravity applies gravity to the view itself inside its parent.

For a button,layout_gravity will apply gravity to whole button whereas android:gravity will apply to its content that is text on Button etc.