# Set text gravity to center

Tags: android, text, textview, center, gravity

i have problem when set text gravity to center it's not appear in the middle ?!

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Large Text Large Text Large Text Large Text Large Text Large Text"
    android:layout_gravity="center"  
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity) thread

Comment: You'll have to post the whole layout xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the whole `TextView` to be centered (which would then center the text) use `android:layout_gravity`

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Large Text Large Text Large Text Large Text Large Text Large Text"
    android:layout_gravity="center"   // Here
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

If this doesn't fix the problem then please post the full xml as you may have other `View`s/properties causing the issue.

Comment: it's doesn't fix the problem i have update my question

Comment: Are you sure that's the complete xml? Because if so, I see no reason for that text to be over to the right. Check in the GUI of your IDE and see where the `TextView` seems to be positioned. Also, try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: You have something else going on that we can't see. I just copied it into my editor and it showed correctly. Did you try cleaning the project as I suggested? What does `AppBaseTheme` do?

Comment: thank u i accidental removed android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" from <application> in manifest ^_^ it's work now

Answer (score 0):

use width to fill parent with the rest

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it just look that way in IDE try to run your app and test.
Happened to me as well but it turned out to be an IDE problem, so just check it out.