# TextView with weight is failing to center text horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, centering, android-layout-weight

I have a view with 2 TextViews in a horizontal LinearLayout, each with a weight of 1.

The second TextView was like this:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/info_button"
                style="@style/TextBlue"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_ten_percent_black_selector"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/card_button_height"
                android:text="@string/shop_info"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
```

For some reason, the text would not center horizontally when rendered. However, if I performed a touch on it, it would center then.

I have a fix where I wrap it in an extra LinearLayout which is given the weight, and center the TextView within that, but I was wondering why that workaround is effective when this isn't.

Also, what extra information might be needed here, since this method of centered text usually works. The views are inflated and added as ListView header.

Comment: Having a similar problem. I'm guessing that `gravity` doesn't work in conjunction with `layout_weight`. What was your solution?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `textAlignment` in your case:

```
android:textAlignment="center"
```

Comment: solved the problem for me, thanks. Can you elaborate why is that worked?

Answer (score 0):

try with `center_vertical` and `center_horizontal` in the textview attribute

```
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
```

Comment: Based on this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html#CENTER
center_vertical|center_horizontal should be identical to center

Comment: @HannahMitt Did you tried with center_vertical and center_horizontal

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you mean `layout_gravity`, not `gravity`

See: [Gravity and layout_gravity on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity)

Comment: I don't, I wanted the internal gravity of the TextView to be center to center the text inside it.

Comment: Got it.  I cannot reproduce this problem with the code you show here. is there 1) any layout in the style; 2) another container, holding the LinearLayout?