# How to position buttons in linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two buttons in a horizontal LinearLayout. They are currently next to each other and the very left. I want to move the second button to the right end of the LinearLayout. 
I tried android:gravity on these buttons but this didn't change the position of them at all.
Thanks

Comment: could your post what you've done?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is to use `RelativeLayout`. You can give your `Button` you want on the right the property `alignParentRight="true"`.

```
<Button
    ...
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

For a horizontal `LinearLayout`, `android:layout_graivty` (which is what you would want instead of `android:gravity`) left and right won't do anything because the `Views` are already placed from right to left.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity) on the difference between `android:gravity` and `android:layout_gravity` if you are uncertain about those.

**Edit**

Depending on *exactly* what you need/want, it **is** possible to do this with a `LinearLayout` though probably still much easier and more flexible with a `RelativeLayout`. Anyway, you can use `weight` to achieve something similar and play with the values. The following gives me a `Button` on the left and a `Button` on the right.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Left Button"/>
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="Right Button"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Right Button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @gunar it is still going to place them on the left and right, correct?

Comment: Yes, undoubtedly yes! :)

Comment: One can very well put a linear layout that has a relative layout with 2 buttons and again: achieved using a LinearLayout :)

Comment: Also, I already said this is probably not ideal in most cases but I wanted you to stop yelling at me so I made the edit :P The whole point of my comment was to try and help you clarify your answer a little better to make it more accurate. "only siths deal in absolutes"

Answer (score 3):

You cannot achieve this using a `LinearLayout`.
Use a `RelativeLayout` instead and place each button relative to `RelativeLayout` right or left. Something like below example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I would be careful saying things like, "You cannot achieve this using...". I obviously agree that using a `RelativeLayout` in this situation is better and easier but it *can* be done with a `LinearLayout`

Comment: @codeMagic: Then please drop an answer with a `LinearLayout` containing only these 2 buttons :)

Comment: I'm not going to do it because, depending on *exactly* what the OP wants, it would be ridiculous. My point is that it **can** be done so saying that the OP "cannot achieve" this is incorrect.

Comment: Then would you do it for me, please? :) I am curious how ... or at least describe how you would do it. I remember I tried it once and I ended up using RL. Again: a LinearLayout with only 2 buttons inside.

Comment: Sure, I got nothing better to do (besides work). See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the left button's `layout_gravity` to `left` (or `start`) and the right button's `layout_gravity` to `right` (or `end`).

The problem is that you are currently using [`gravity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:gravity) which

> Specifies how an object should position its content, on both the X and Y axes, within its own bounds.

Instead, you should use [`layout_gravity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity) that is

> Standard gravity constant that a child supplies to its parent. Defines how the child view should be positioned, on both the X and Y axes, within its enclosing layout.

In other words - you are currently telling the buttons how to align their child views, instead of telling them how to be aligned within their parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `android:layout_weight='1'` and both buttons will share the screen equally(side by side) or if you want the extra space between them, you can place a button each in a linear layout and set the `android:layout_gravity` to `left` and `right`for each.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `RelativeLayout` and set values to `layout_marginLeft`, `layout_marginTop`, etc.

eg.
    `android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"`

Answer (score 0):

make linearLayout orientation **Vertical** and set button's gravity => **center** and as you want..