# How can I replace view to the left in android

Tags: android

I tried this

```
android:layout_gravity="left"
```

but it doesn't work

here's the code :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/title" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/android-gravity-and-layout-gravity

Comment: You could also use `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `EditText` left of the `TextView`, swap them:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No , that's not the problem , the textview and the edittext are conjoined and i want to separate them .

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you elaborate?