# Linear layout gravity and place item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, layout-gravity

today i'm working on layout and i have a question , basic i think.

I have a linear layout and an imageview on it. I want to display the image and the left or on the right of the layout

I tried , layout_gravity
It's important to precise that i want to do it on a linear and not on a relative or other stuff.

Thanks by advance , a screen to precise my question

http://hpics.li/fc67805

my linear with the image

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Reboot"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/arreter" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set layout_width to wrap_content ?

Comment: Check my answer to place the ImageView to either right or left. The accepted answer doesn't work if you want to place the IV to right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this layout to align the ImageView to either right/left

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Reboot"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_gravity="left"         // you can use right also. It works.
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Your LinearLayout orientation is `horizontal`, so you can place the child views in `top and bottom` using `android:layout_gravity`. For `horizontal` LinearLayout `right and left` doesn't work, they work only for `vertical` LinearLayout. Hope this information is useful :)

Comment: Will you please expound why it is redundant?

Comment: Hmm , you'have a part of the response , thanks but now , here is the problem , i want the both imageview on the same line One on left , one on right http://hpics.li/75900a6

Comment: Can you please post it as different question and give me the link here?

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that your `ImageView` is "matching" the size of the parent `LinearLayout`, so there's no way to align it to either the left or the right...it's pointless in this case because the view takes the whole space anyway. If you really want to visualize the effect of the image being aligned to either the left or the right of its parent, you can change the `layout_width` and `layout_height` of the `ImageView` to `wrap_content` as below...

```
     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Reboot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/arreter" />
```

also, notice that I removed the `layout_weight` attribute since it is also useless for a single child view inside a `LinearLayout`

Comment: You beat me to it! Nice answer ;)

Comment: @G.T. sorry mate, that happens sometimes ;)

Comment: @Leo does this solution works to place the ImageView to the right? And I don't think `android:layout_gravity="left"` is required here.

Comment: @Aniruddha if you change the `layout_gravity` attribute to `right`...yes

Comment: @Leo please check by changing the value to `right`. It will not work.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**To Left Side**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Reboot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**To Right Side**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Reboot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This question has probably already been answered but in case someone else finds this**

Layout_gravity and Gravity are different. Layout_gravity changes the position of the item within its ViewGroup while andorid:gravity changes the position of the item's contents.

There's a good discussion about the difference
 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android)

Now, since both the LinearLayout's width and the ImageView's width are match_parent, layout_gravity won't work because they're already the same size.
You need to keep the LinearLayout's width at **match_parent** and change the ImageView's width to **wrap_content**. Then, you can use **android:layout_gravity**="right" or **android:layout_gravity**="left" to move the image right or left.

NOTE: This also applies to moving an image up/down. Just change the ViewGroup's and ImageView's height instead of the width and use android:layout_gravity="top" or android:layout_gravity="bottom"