# Android-How to center my custom View in LinearLayout?

Tags: android, layout, center

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <com.example.root.howold.MyRing
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I also try to set **gravity** and **layout_gravity**, but they don't work actually.

How can I make MyRing(my custom View) **center** in Layout?

Comment: Please share entire xml file

Comment: @BP233, bhavesh is right. share your entire xml.

Answer (score 4):

```
Try this:-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.example.root.howold.MyRing
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this:
[Gravity and layout_gravity on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android)

To make your view aligned center, you can:

**LinearLayout case1:** 
"android:gravity" is for it's children views. 
**If this doesn't works, check it's parent view's width and height.**
And, set parent's width and height to bigger size.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**LinearLayout case2:** 
"android:layout_gravity" is for it self, if parent view has empty spaces.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="TEST" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**RelativeLayout**
You can use "android:layout_centerInParent" for RelativeLayout.

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="TEST" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using root layout as linear layout. You can use below text that will set your custom view to center.

Depends on your requirement you can user

```
 layout_gravity="center"
```

(or)

```
layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

(or)

```
layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Below is the xml which has custom view.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <!-- Here you may some other views -->

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <com.purpletalk.root.sampledemo.MyRing
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="hellooooo" />
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linear Layout,

Option 1: Add `android:gravity` to the parent view, to center all its child
          views.
Example:

```
<LinearLayout
           android:gravity="center">
           <TextView/>   
           <TextView/>  // Both these textviews will be aligned center
           </LinearLayout>
```

Option 2: If you want to center only a child view, then add the attribute 
          `android:layout_gravity="center"` to the childview tag.

```
<LinearLayout>
           <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center"  // Only this textview will be aligned center
           />
           <TextView/>
           </LinearLayout>
```