# Why layout_gravity property doesn't show up in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

I've been trying to center a logo (an ImageView) in the ToolBar. I finally did it but the main reason it took so long, I couldn't find layout_gravity property in auto-complete or in Android Studio's Design pane> Properties table. Only gravity related property is foregroundGravity.

Now, I think ImageView is an ImageView. It must have layout_gravity where ever it is but not being able to find the property made me think it is not available when you use android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar..
Has anyone had a similar experience or do you know why it happens?

Below is my code and the min API level is 10.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/comp_logo"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `layout_` prefix on an attribute indicates that attribute is a property *of the parent View's LayoutParams*.

In the layout you posted for example, the `layout_gravity` on your `ImageView` is used to tell the `Toolbar` where to position the image. The `ImageView` itself does nothing with that attribute.

Note that many Views (such as TextView) do support a `gravity` attribute, which is how that View will layout its own content. `layout_gravity` will position the View as a whole within its parent, whereas `gravity` positions the View's content within that View. See also: [Gravity and layout_gravity on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android?rq=1).

The reason Android Studio isn't offering `layout_gravity` as an option on your Toolbar is that in this layout your Toolbar has no parent, and thus Android Studio has no idea what layout attributes are available to it. This makes sense, as your layouts should be completely independent of any parent that you may put them in.

Comment: Thanks @Tanis.7x! I think I am about to understand. But...If Android Studio doesn't know which properties available to the View why does it offer the layout_margin properties? My guess is, layout_margin properties are available to every View by default. Am I correct? Where should I look to find out?

Comment: I can't speak to why it offers `layout_margin`- it is only available when the parent ViewGroup's LayoutParams extend [`MarginLayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html), but you are correct that that it is fairly common.