# Android: Position Widget in the center

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to learn about Animation and am using following layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumb_button_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_1" />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

However, this will  not center the ImageButton vertically.  It does it only horizontally.  I tried layout_gravity "center", "center_vertical", "center_horizontal" without success.  The best I got is this:
[image]

but I need to get this:

[image]

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try android:gravity="center" to your LinearLayout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="16dp"
       android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumb_button_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_1" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

[difference between gravity and layout_gravity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android)

Comment: Thank you Krupal, that fixed it.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/thumb_button_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

There is problem in wrap_content in layout height and width in your imagebutton widget