# android:layout_gravity="center" can't set the button in the center of titlebar?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-gravity

I am really a new fresher in android,
I know `android:layout_gravity` sets the gravity of the `View` or `Layout` in its parent.And `android:gravity` sets the gravity of the content of the `View` its used on.[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android)

But when I set the titlebar `Linearlayout` `gravity="center"`,the button did sit in the center

But when I delete `gravity="center"` in the head of `LinerLayout`,then add `layout_gravity="center"` in the button,the button sit in the left?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Change LinearLayout Height to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`.

Comment: use gravity="center" inside linear layout

Comment: hi Dhaval,but it no longer a title bar

Comment: Thanks,hetal. That's true as I describe in the question. What I asking is why I can't use `layout_gravity="center"` to set the button in the center

Comment: if you want to use layout_gravity="center" then width of you button should be match_parent

Comment: please up vote my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just give orientation to your `LinearLayout`, rest all things are perfect

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Back"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah! Is that means `layout_gravity` must work with `LinearLayout orientation` ? If I add two other widget `TextView` and `Button`,

Answer (score 2):

check the following code and button at center:

```
 <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">
          <Button
              android:layout_width="100dp"
              android:layout_height="100dp"
              android:layout_gravity="center"/>
     </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Back"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
```

Answer (score 0):

add `android:orientation="vertical"` in the LinearLayout