# Issue with GIF image

Tags: android

So I am using a GIF in my app . But when I install the app in other device the GIF doesn't fit in the screen or it's not on the place it should be. Anyone have solution for this ?

Comment: Please, post your code

Comment: Both of them. Position of elements can be set directly in xml but also programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Class:

```
 package com.example.cyril.tryapp;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Movie;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.View;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class GifView extends View {

    private InputStream gifInputStream;
    private Movie gifMovie;
    private int movieWidth = 150, movieHeight = 500;
    private long movieDuration;
    private long mMovieStart;

    public GifView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                   int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context){
        setFocusable(true);
        gifInputStream = context.getResources()
                .openRawResource(R.drawable.maestragif);

        gifMovie = Movie.decodeStream(gifInputStream);
        movieWidth = gifMovie.width();
        movieHeight = gifMovie.height();
        movieDuration = gifMovie.duration();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, 
            int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(movieWidth, movieHeight);
    }

    public int getMovieWidth(){
        return movieWidth;
    }

    public int getMovieHeight(){
        return movieHeight;
    }

    public long getMovieDuration(){
        return movieDuration;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (mMovieStart == 0) {   // first time
            mMovieStart = now;
        }

        if (gifMovie != null) {

            int dur = gifMovie.duration();
            if (dur == 0) {
                dur = 1000;
            }

            int relTime = (int)((now - mMovieStart) % dur);

            gifMovie.setTime(relTime);

            gifMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
            invalidate();

        }

    }

}
```

XML:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_mainplain"
    android:layout_gravity="center">



<com.example.cyril.tryapp.GifView
        android:id="@+id/gifview"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

    <com.example.cyril.tryapp.GifView2
        android:id="@+id/gifview2"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your gif will not fit all screens because you set the width and heignt attributes with a specific value:

```
android:layout_width="130dp"
android:layout_height="230dp"
```

DP values are density independent, but they're not the same size on every screens, a scaling factor is applied to convert the DP value to a PX value

Comment: uhm so what should I put there so it would fit in other screens ?

Comment: You want to fit the whole screen with the image or you want some margins?

Comment: no not the whole screen. I want the first gif in the left side of the screen and the other in the top part .

Comment: You can use the `weight` attribute: http://www.chess-ix.com/blog/the-use-of-layout_weight-with-android-layouts/ and you can use the `gravity` / `layout_gravity` : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3482757/5778152