# textAlignement center not working on jellyBean

Tags: android, xml

I've made an XML which include a `TextView` having a `textAlignement:center` in the following code :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"
            android:text="gestion"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/GoGestion"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></View>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Creation Sav"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></View>
     <Button
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"
            android:text="Archive"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/GoArchive"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And the fact is that My textView isn't centered on a tablet having 4.1.2 version (jellybean) but is on the other tablet 4.4.2 (kitkat).
My app compiles with `minSdkVersion 15` so jellybean is more recent. Nowhere in the doc is specified that Jellybean does not run textAlignement.

Why is it not working on jelylbean and how can I fix this?

Comment: use gravity for more info http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3agravity

Comment: but the gravity of my TextView is already center too, i've tried to remove the alignement and it doesn't change anything

Comment: dude not layout_gravity you need to set android:gravity="center"

Comment: oh right those are different things... i'm sorry

Comment: yup for that i posted the answer also

Comment: Thanks for all the fast help from everyone, i'll accept answer when i'll be able to in a few minutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  <TextView
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Creation Sav"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
```

change to

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Creation Sav"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
```

> `android:gravity` sets the gravity of the contents wiz.`subviews` inside `container`.
>
> `android:layout_gravity` sets the gravity of the `View/Layout` relative
>   to its parent `Layout/Container`. Everything with `layout_` defines something that effects the elements outside.

Answer (score 5):

You can set this in your `TextView`

```
 android:gravity="center"
```

> Place the object in the center of its container in both the vertical
>   and horizontal axis, not changing its size.

Please check **[Gravity and layout_gravity on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android)** . Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

Put this code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/GoGestion"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"
            android:text="gestion" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"></View>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Creation Sav"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.01"></View>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/GoArchive"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.24"
            android:text="Archive" />
    </LinearLayout>
```