# TextView and RadioGroup alignment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-radiogroup

I am having trouble getting my `TextView` and `RadioGroup` in the right position.

I want the `TextView` to have its own row and the `RadioGroup` to have its own as well. Perhaps also make it easily adjustable so that I can change the spacing between the two.

The `TextView` and `RadioGroup` are currently on top of each other.

[image]

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dueDateSection"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_edit_item_layout_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_edit_item_layout_vertical_margin"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tvPriorityLabel"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/priorityChoice"/>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/priorityChoice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/lowPriority"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/priorityLow"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/medPriority"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/priorityMedium" />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/highPriority"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/priorityHigh" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to align your RadioGroup under your TextView. You should add the id attribute to the TextView and then set the RadioGroup to be below it:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tvPriorityLabel"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/priorityChoice"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/priorityChoice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_view">
```

Also note that you do not need the [android:gravity attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android) for positioning individual views.

Make sure to checkout the docs on [RelativeLayouts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) and [LinearLayouts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

You need to use property to put view below one another in relative layouts

> android:layout_below="@+id/text"

```
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dueDateSection"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="PriorityLabel"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/priorityChoice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/lowPriority"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Low" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/medPriority"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/highPriority"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="yHigh" />
    </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this... take all in One Row**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

      android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Label"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/priorityChoice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/lowPriority"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Low"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/medPriority"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Medium" />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/highPriority"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="High" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Or As You want**

```
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Label"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

      />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/priorityChoice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
       >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/lowPriority"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Low"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/medPriority"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/highPriority"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="High" />
    </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**if You want to radio Group center than take in radio group

```
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```