# android:gravity not changing the position of the text in a TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am writing code for an activity that has a table that initially contains 2 rows(see screenshot). I would like the text in those 2 rows to be in the center(not the TextView).

However, setting `android:gravity = "center"` or  `android:gravity = "center_horizontal"` does not affect the text at all.
What am I missing?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq8Fk.png)

> activity_game.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="16dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tl1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tr_header_p1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/player1_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Player 1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Guess"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Bulls"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Cows"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tl2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tr_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/player2_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Player 2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tr_header2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Guess"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Bulls"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Cows"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this should work,

add `android:gravity="center"` to your `@+id/tr_header_p1` and `@+id/tr_header`
like,

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tr_header_p1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp">
```

and

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tr_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp">
```

this might helps you

**EDIT 1**

or you need to mention the `android:layout_weight="1"` to your TextView. like

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/player2_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Player 2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
```

Comment: Works. Can you explain why? Shouldn't this only shift the TextView to the center but since the layout_width of the TextView is match_parent, it should not have an effect at all.

Comment: If my answer helps you means kindly mark as answer and close the question .

Comment: your parent TableLayout having weight=1 but , you didn't mention any weight to your child. if u give same weight (1) to your child means , the problem will be solve

Answer (score 0):

try for the TableRow parent of TextView

```
android:gravity="CENTER_HORIZONTAL"
```

the default layout of a table it's applied to children nodes, as described in documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html)

Comment: @SajalNarang I changed the answer, apply `center_horizontal` to the parent of those textviews

Comment: Adding the android:gravity attribute to the parent does the trick, but I don't understand why. As far as I know, it will try aligning the TextView to the center of the TableRow, but fail because the layout_width of the TextView is set to match_parent. Why does it have any effect on the contents of the TextView?

Comment: @SajalNarang, as in html language, the default layout of a table it's applied to children nodes

Comment: then shouldn't my code do the same thing? I am just applying the layout directly to the child.

Comment: but if you do it in the html, it will not work :) usually you apply css style on the tablerow, not in the spans and div inside the table cell (I'm talking about layout styles

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tl1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_header_p1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/player1_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"

                android:text="Player 1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Guess"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Bulls"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Cows"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tl2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/player2_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Player 2"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_header2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Guess"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Bulls"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Cows"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `layout_width` to `wrap_content` and then set `layout_gravity` to `center`.

That align the entire TextView and not the text inside it

Answer (score 0):

What if you used **android:layout_gravity** from your **TextView** which is gonna affect the position of the element according its parent? There's a thread explaining the difference between both below

[Gravity and layout_gravity on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android)

Comment: The android:layout_width of the TextView is set to match_parent. So android:layout_gravity should not have any effect on the position, right?

Comment: You are right! If you change to **wrap_content** you should be good. But it is up you and your project scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tr_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/player2_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Player 2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </TableRow>
```

This is working for me