# In android, how to make empty TextView stay in the middle vertically?

Tags: android

In android, I want to add an empty message in the middle of screen when my GridView is empty. But the layout below makes the text in the middle-top of the screen. How can I make the text in the middle also in vertical direction ?

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);        
TextView emptyText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.empty);
gridview.setEmptyView(emptyText);



   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/gridview"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:columnWidth="100dp"
       android:numColumns="auto_fit"
       android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
       android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
       android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
       android:gravity="center"

       />


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="No project files found"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="No project files found"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

Comment: @mehdiakbarian That doesn't work in a LinearLayout for vertically centering

Comment: @cricket_007 im sure its work :D

Comment: @mehdiakbarian  using your TextView.  the text is not displayed at all. Why ?

Comment: @J.Doe because of grid view! if your gridview fill with data it will get all space of screen and textView will go out!! its better handle this with RelativeLayout

Comment: This should help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the parent view as RelativeLayout and then set 
`centerInParent="true"` for TextView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey">

    <TextView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In my original code; changed to RelativeLayout and add layout_centerInParent = "true" in TextView.   The text is not displayed at all.

Comment: change android:textColor="#FFFFFF" to something else, this is setting color to white

Comment: @EkanshRastogi What if the theme background is dark?

Comment: @EkanshRastogi  Yes. it works now. textColor was same as the background.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to make the parent view a Relative layout, try this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="No project files found"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Comment: This method makes the text appear at the left-top corner.

Comment: that's weird, what happens if you delete the `GridView` block, does it center then?

Comment: How to remove gridview. In my code I need to add the text view as empty view to the gridView.

Comment: You can't add a `TextView` as a child to `GridView`, in Android Studio it won't even render the preview screen if you tried.

Comment: Nice option iff GridView visibility is set to gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="No project files found"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Comment: When your gridview is empty change its visibility to gone then the text will be visible in center

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to place the TextView center vertical is to make the parent layout a RelativeLayout and place the TextView in a LinearLayout centered vertical to the LinearLayout which is centered to the parent layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:gravity="center"

    />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="No project files found"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You added extra complexity by adding LinearLayout as root of TextView

Comment: without the LinearLayout, i don't think it is possible to set the TextView center vertical. The LinearLayout was used to Hold the TextView center in parent and to make it possible to set TextView center vertical.

Comment: Instead of doing that, you can add the centerInParent attribute to the TextView

Comment: oh i think i understand the J.Doe now, the TextView should be centered of the parent view not centered vertical of the parent view. Good one @Krrishnaaaa