# Linear Layout:How to fill the whole width of screen?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I've following layout file, which creates linear layout inside the relative layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#eeeeee">

<LinearLayout            // I want this to fill the whole width of screen.
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="50px"
    android:background="#666666"


    >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/newEvent"
        android:hint="Enter the Name of Event"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select Location"
    android:id="@+id/pickerButton"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/newEvent"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/newEvent" />



</LinearLayout>

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Set Remainder"
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="View All"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_below="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your Location Will Appear Here"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"

    android:layout_above="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Using this code, I got following layout:

[image]

But There are spaces left in left, right and top of the gray color (linear-Layout). I don't want these space. I want to fill the whole width with gray color. What changes should I make in my `xml` to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the answers. But after resolving this, I'm getting my text box and button at the bottom of the gray box, as shown in following figure:

[image]

For this, I've already tried `"android:gravity="center_horizontal"` , `"android:gravity="center_vertical"`  and `"android:gravity="center"`. I've also tried `padding-bottom`.

But this is not working.

Comment: Remove the padding attributes from the parent `RelativeLayout`, also set an orientation for your `LinearLayout`

Comment: No problem - Always pays to check the view hierarchy with issues like this

Comment: @MarkKeen see the edits.

Comment: I believe you should read this post on gravity. Otherwise, if you want to center things, use a RelativeLayout around the view you want centered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

lines from parent `RelativeLayout`

```
<LinearLayout            
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="50px"
    android:background="#666666"  
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/newEvent"
        android:hint="Enter the Name of Event"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Location"
        android:id="@+id/pickerButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you! Now my button and the text box are at bottom of the gray box. Is there any way to align it in center?

Comment: set `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` or `android:gravity="center"` to your `LinearLayout`

Comment: I think it should be `center_vertical` .

Comment: You can set vertically, horizontally or both depending on your requirement. :)

Comment: Then you can try with `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical` on your text box and button

Comment: Solved problem my self: edited `android:paddingTop="25px"`  and `android:paddingBottom="25px"` in linear layout.

Comment: Try remove any padding from `LinearLayout` and add `android:gravity="center_vertical"`. For my case its working fine. To see the output set a large height for `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the top part of your Relative layout ot this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#eeeeee">
```

**EDIT:**

Change your LinearLayout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout          
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="50px"
    android:background="#666666">

    <LinearLayout          
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/newEvent"
            android:hint="Enter the Name of Event" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select Location"
            android:id="@+id/pickerButton" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you! Now my button and the text box are at bottom of the gray box. Is there any way to align it in center?

Comment: @14bce109 I have updated my answer, take a look at it

Comment: not working. See the exact problem in my edited question

Comment: Did you set gravity to vertical?

Comment: @14bce109 try new solution given in answer. Replace your LinearLayout with the code given

Comment: The linear layout shifted left side instead of center

Comment: Solved problem my self: edited `android:paddingTop="25px"`  and `android:paddingBottom="25px"` in linear layout

Comment: LinearLayout is set to match_parent. It can't shift anywhere in horizontal direction. What do you mean by that?

Comment: For future, avoid using `px` to specify the distance. Use `dp` instead. It will make sure that the paddings and margins are equal on all devices

Answer (score 0):

In LinearLayout you are using android:paddingTop="50px". Instead use top and bottom padding 25px each.

Comment: just copied what I've mentioned in comments