# LinearLayout is not filling whole screen width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have made a view for advertisements list and LinearLayout is not filling whole screen width, checked all the code and I don't understand where I am mistaken. Here is the code of my LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@id/advertisement_list_container"
android:paddingTop="0.0dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<TextView
    android:id="@id/advertisement_list_datetime"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_margin_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/small_listing_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_margin_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/small_listing_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/listing_margin"
    android:text="@string/advertisement_list_datetime"
    style="@style/TextWhiteNormalBoldGreyBackground" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_margin_horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_margin_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@id/advertisement_list_from_city"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/listing_margin"
            android:text="@string/advertisement_list_from_city"
            style="@style/TextNormalBold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@id/advertisement_list_tire"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/tire_margin"
            android:text="@string/advertisement_list_tire"
            style="@style/TextNormalBold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@id/advertisement_list_to_city"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/tire_margin"
            android:text="@string/advertisement_list_to_city"
            style="@style/TextNormalBold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_margin_vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/advertisement_list_user_avatar"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_result_size_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_result_size_height"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_default_avatar" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/listing_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1.0">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/advertisement_list_user_name"
                    android:text="@string/advertisement_list_user_name"
                    style="@style/TextDarkBlueNormalBold" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/advertisement_list_user_age"
                    android:text="@string/advertisement_list_user_age"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/small"
                    style="@style/TextGreyNormal" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/text_normal"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_small"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_star_gold_no_border"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/advertisement_list_user_rating"
                    android:text="@string/advertisement_list_user_rating"
                    style="@style/TextNormalBold" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/advertisement_list_user_rate"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_micro"
                    android:text="@string/advertisement_list_user_rate"
                    style="@style/TextGreyNormal" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/text_normal"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/small"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_car_blue"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/advertisement_list_user_car"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/small"
                    android:text="@string/advertisement_list_user_car"
                    style="@style/TextNormalBold" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/advertisement_list_user_car_y"
                    android:text="@string/advertisement_list_user_car_y"
                    style="@style/TextGreyNormal" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/text_normal"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/small"
                    android:tint="@color/text_dark_blue"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_phone"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/advertisement_list_user_phone"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/small"
                    android:text="@string/advertisement_list_user_phone"
                    style="@style/TextNormalBold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_margin_vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2.0">
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@id/advertisement_list_free_seats"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/advertisement_list_free_seats"
                style="@style/TextDarkBlueMediumBold" />
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@id/advertisement_list_free_seats"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/advertisement_list_free_seats"
                android:lines="2"
                style="@style/TextDarkBlueSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2.0">
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@id/advertisement_list_price"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/advertisement_list_price"
                style="@style/TextDarkBlueMediumBold" />
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@id/advertisement_list_ride_price"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/advertisement_list_ride_price"
                android:lines="2"
                style="@style/TextDarkBlueSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/divider"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the result what I see in my app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/loInn.jpg

So advertisement must fill whole screen width.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linear Layout:How to fill the whole width of screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900772/linear-layouthow-to-fill-the-whole-width-of-screen)

Comment: post your styles and dimen code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed main `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` and it fixed my issue!