# center multiple RelativeLayout inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Inside a `linearLayout` I have put three `RelativeLayout`s with `weight = 1`. I want `RelativeLayout`s to be in the center of the screen. How can I manage their position?

below is my `xml` code:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_circular_items"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_bg_profile_img"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:background="@color/color_backgrounds_light">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_txt_view"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_view_scores"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2843"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/dim_txt_size_times"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:foregroundGravity="center"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_view_scores_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="scores"
                    android:layout_below="@id/txt_view_scores"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/dim_txt_size_times_title"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:foregroundGravity="center"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_txt_view"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_view_purchase"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="12"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/dim_txt_size_times"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:foregroundGravity="center"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_view_purchase_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="purchase"
                    android:layout_below="@id/txt_view_purchase"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/dim_txt_size_times_title"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:foregroundGravity="center"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_txt_view"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_view_cash"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="21450"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/dim_txt_size_times"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:foregroundGravity="center"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_view_cash_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="cash"
                    android:layout_below="@id/txt_view_cash"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/dim_txt_size_times_title"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:foregroundGravity="center"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

and this is the `screen shot` of output:

[image]

I want the red spaces be equal.

Comment: Set _android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"_ for _LinearLayout_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your top LinearLayout

simply use `android:gravity="center"`

It will definitely work. If it does not work remove all gravity from RelativeLayout. Only use `android:gravity="center"` in top LinearLayout.

Comment: it's working! No need to remove `gravity` from `RelativeLayout`. just working with the first two lines.

Comment: yeah you are right. Actually gravity is a property of LinearLayout, so if you use gravity inside RelativeLayout it would not effect anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to this code and edit according your need

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/layout_circular_items"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_view_scores"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="2843" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_view_scores_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt_view_scores"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="scores" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_view_purchase"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="12" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_view_purchase_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt_view_purchase"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="purchase" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_view_cash"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="21450" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_view_cash_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt_view_cash"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="cash" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is answered correctly but just want to add more explanation.

When you want to change the children positions you must work with their parent `gravity`, No need to change the children gravity. In your case you must simply change your `LinearLayout`'s gravity to `center` or `center_horizontal` like this:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_circular_items"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            <!-- Add this line-->
            android:gravity="center" 
> ...
```

> `android:gravity` is the Inside gravity of that View. This means, in
>   which direction it's contents should align.

This link is also useful to find more info about `gravity` and `layout_gravity`:

[Gravity and layout_gravity on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android)