# How to align this layout. I'm using layout weight

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

**XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/fragone"
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_weight="8"
              android:background="#4caad4"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="62dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
</Linearlayout>
```

**PREVIEW :**[image]

It works perfectly, but I want to align text view. How do they do it? In this size perfect for horizontal view. In portrait view it align looks like this picture. How to set both horizontal & portrait view on same?

Comment: You can use this link: [Gravity and layout_gravity on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

where do you want to align your textview,
to right, left or center or any predefined position

I am exactly not clear about your ques, please specify it and tell what you want exactly.

Here I have fixed some lines of your layout, as you are not very specific to your question

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragone"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#4caad4"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="8">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i want to add textview below the image

Comment: Here,I have edited the ans for you, change the weight if you want a bigger or smaller textView or imageView

Comment: Let me know if this solves your problem, and don't forget to upvote

Comment: i want to align textview one by one in vertical view

Comment: use layout weight to align, suppose in your case your linear layout contain "weight sum"=8 means whole screen is divided into 8 section.

Comment: if orientation is vertical

Comment: set height to 0dp and layout_weight as you want

Comment: vise versa for horizontal layout,

Comment: yes.i get this.but i have another problem pop up.it is when i run small size emulator in horizontal view second textview not fully show.how to show it?

Comment: the xml is correct, weather you open in horizontal or vertical mode. for better understanding i have putted a textview in it which is centered. I checked it in 4 devices.

Comment: maybe you are entering more than one lines in textview, which may occupy the space of other textview too.

Comment: its because you 2nd last textview contains more than one line

Comment: it should be not more than the weight height, and according to your ques. the above xml is working fine, and below is the image of it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Horizontal view]

[image: Vertical view]

it is working fine in both mode.

Comment: what is difference weightsum & layout_weight?

Comment: weightsum defines how much weight you have with you and layout_weight is how much you are giving from weightsum.

Comment: I am also a beginner dude, perhaps you can give a up vote, if my ans is right.

Comment: how to vote? & if any further doubts how i contact you?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.   i have this message