# Android layout strange TextView behaviour in editor

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an `xml` layout file that is used to show a `ListView` item. Here is `xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/task_item_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/task_item_icon_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_icon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/stat_notify_sync" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="appName"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/additional_info_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.19">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="0,1 $"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want `TextView` with id `price` to have gravity value set to center. But when I do it, `item_text` somewhy jumps to the center. This behaviour can be seen only in editor, everything is fine on my device.

Layout when `price` gravity value is not set:

[image: no gravity]

Layout when `price` gravity value is set to center:

[image: gravity: center]

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

**UPD**: Do not edit my question: I change gravity of `price` TextView, and `item_text` is the one that changes. This is the strange behaviour I am asking about.

Comment: Why do you need a RelativeLayout around that imageview or text view? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android

Comment: @cricket_007 I need RelativeLayout to set margins for `price`. Both TextViews have `gravity` attributes set, so it must change only the contents.

Comment: Do you really need a RelativeLayout to set margins?

Comment: @cricket_007 well, in fact, I don't. I need this RelativeLayout because I am going to add other Views into it and show the needed ones depending on context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `TextView` with id `item_text` add

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

It happens because there is an inconsistent specification between `text_alignment` and `gravity`. Older phones ignore `text_alignment`, which explains why it works on your device.

Comment: Exactly the same result.

Comment: I think you wanted center_vertical?

Comment: Are you sure? I can see the issue on mine, and putting this line in fixes it. Make sure everything is up to date and the preview API Version is the "Automatically pick best"

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, sorry, I used `android:gravity` instead of `android:layout_gravity`. Now I use both(center for `android:layout_gravity` and center_vertical for `android:gravity`). Thanks, this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make the following changes

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/additional_info_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.19">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/price"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" //here
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="0,1 $"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" //add this
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: But I am going to use billynomates` solution, because I am going to add other Views into this RelativeLayout.