# How to put my title center horizontal in popup window?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

This is my output: 
[image]

Here is the layout-code for the `popup-window`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_custom_layout_handlungsleitfaden_strassenfuehrer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib_close_handlungsleitfaden_strassenfuehrer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@null"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_handlungsleitfaden_strassenfuehrer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:text="Anlage erfolgreich instand gesetzt"
            android:textColor="#32D732"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:padding="25sp"/>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_strassenfuehrer_handlungsleitfaden"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F7F7F7"
            android:padding="25dp">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
                android:padding="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                    android:text="Störungscode"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                    android:text="Test"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
                android:padding="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                    android:text="Bezeichnung"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                    android:text="Test"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
                android:padding="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                    android:text="Zeitstempel Fehler"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                    android:text="Test"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
                android:padding="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                    android:text="Zeitstempel Instandsetzung"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                    android:text="Test"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
                android:padding="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                    android:text="Dauer Anlagenstillstand"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                    android:text="Test"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
                android:padding="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                    android:text="Anlagen ID"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                    android:text="Test"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_last_bg"
                android:padding="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                    android:text="Projekt"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                    android:text="Test"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_handlungsleitfaden_strassenfuehrer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:text="Bewertung des Handlungsleitfadens"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="25sp"/>

        <com.hsalf.smilerating.SmileRating
            android:id="@+id/smile_rating_handlungsleitfaden_strassenfuehrer"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="25sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am new in android, and tried some things, because I would like that the title, which is in green color shall be `center_horizontal`. But it does not look like this. If you see the title "Bewertung des Handlungsleitfadens", it looks more `center horizontal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:gravity="center"` in to your textview

And Update

`android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`

`android:layout_width="match_parent"`

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_handlungsleitfaden_strassenfuehrer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Anlage erfolgreich instand gesetzt"
        android:textColor="#32D732"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:padding="25sp"/>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: thanks! It worked :) I will accept your answear in 5 minutes. Anyway, could you pls explain, what you did? Because layout_gravity means the layout of the hole Textview and center, of its childrean?

Comment: From what I can gather layout_gravity is the gravity of that view inside its parent, and gravity is the gravity of the children inside that view.
refer Link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/difference-between-gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: thanks, I understand now :)

Comment: Anytime welcome happy to help you.