# How can I horizontally center this layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have two devices which I test this apk with and on one of them it is almost centered and on the other it is aligned to the left.

The layout in question is the one labeled Custom Layout

[image]

This is what happens when I run the app on the emulator. Setting the horizontal constraint bias to 0 has not worked by the way.

displayed inside the emulator

[image]

Comment: You mean centered vertically?

Comment: why are you giving fixed layout size instead of match_parent + wrap_content. Are you trying to fire this layout in Dialog mode?

Comment: please provide the component tree of your custom_layout.xml. The problem might be the width of the root view

Comment: Is the `custom_layout.xml` used inside an `AlertDialog` or some other dialog like a `PopupWindow` for instance?

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for `android:layout_gravity`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/difference-between-gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android) could be useful for understanding