# Why isn't my view centering horizontally in my linear layout?

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to get the chronometer (child of textview) to center in this horizontal linear layout for a few hours.  I've looked on here and saw everyone mentioning the gravity attribute.  I changed this and experimented with other attributes to no success.  Below is the XML from android studio.  What am I doing wrong?

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/statusDisplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Score" />

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should use layout_gravity for your child views. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3482757/5802513).

Comment: Also linearLayouts have really poor performance. Consider using constraint layout.

Comment: Like the gravity of our planet applies to us, the gravity of a parent is applied to its children. Setting the gravity for the LinearLayout should affect the positioning of all its children.

Comment: Thanks Tiago.  I'm going to try using a constraint layout.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/statusDisplay"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="20dp"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:gravity="center">

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="Score" />

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Otherwise, You can use RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/statusDisplay"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="Score"/>

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use **Gravity** property in the parent layout. Or use a **RelativeLayout** as a parent instead and  use attribute layout:center_Horizontal ="true" on the parent.