# Start Button from Right to Left Instead of Left to Right

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, material-components, material-components-android

I am trying to make it so that the `Button` in the `LinearLayout` starts from the right side and to set the `Button` `5dp` from the right edge of the `LinearLayout`, with the `TextView` showing to the left of the button.  Currently, it only allows to set the button from the "left" edge of the linear layout. I've tried all sorts of ways but nothing seems to work.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/remote_button_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_remote_button"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:text="Example Text"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/mmedium"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_remote_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_remote_button"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/logo"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the page what should be look like?

Comment: It seems that you can use only 1 button instead of a LL+TV+BT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `android:gravity="right"` in Layout. So all the inner widgets will be set from right to left manner. Like below.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/remote_button_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:gravity="right
                android:background="@drawable/btn_remote_button"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
```

Comment: If I were to make the identical button and textview on the left(on each side now), would I need to make a separate LinearLayout and combine it?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `android:layout_weight=1` parametr to TextView

Answer (score 1):

Use layoutGravity tag in your xml as (right, left)

Answer (score 1):

Use this android:layout_gravity as (left,right) you can refer this link [What is the difference between gravity and layout_gravity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/what-is-the-difference-between-gravity-and-layout-gravity-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can just change add the `android:gravity="right"` attribute in your `LinearLayout`.

```
  <LinearLayout
      android:gravity="right"
```

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]

You can also consider to do something different using a `MaterialButton` adding the text and the icon.

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
        app:icon="@drawable/..."
        app:iconGravity="end"
        android:text="@string/..."/>
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make an identical button and textview on each side(left and right) or would I need to make a separate LinearLayout?

Comment: Do you mean something like [text - icon - text] ?

Comment: something like [icon-text   space        text-icon]

Comment: You need 2 buttons

Comment: I put in two button; sorry i meant [button-text space text-button]; I was curious if it were possible, since I have the android:gravity="right, if theres a way to provide a android:gravity="left" to the other button-text

Comment: Use a RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout