# center 5 items packed in linear layout

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

I have 5 items.

I want to center all of them horizontally and make them packed to each other.

I know in constraint layout I would create a horizontal chain and `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle=”packed”`

But is it possible to do with `LinearLayout`? how?

here is my try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="DOT" />

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"



      android:text="BBB" />


</LinearLayout>
```

but it's not packed in the middle:

[image]

Comment: Do you have the preview example of what you mean?

Comment: @ErwinKurniawanA I added my code. I would expect the space to before the AAAA and after the BBB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android:gravity="center"` in your LinearLayout.

You have to put the textviews into another linealayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DOT" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="BBB" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26190050/3528912 the difference between gravity and layout_gravity. But maybe we are talking past each other. You could port an example to exactly know what you mean.

Comment: for me: when I set parent's gravity it's equal to setting the child's layout_gravity. no?

Comment: For example, how would you set only one element to be in the center and the rest packed to it with a fix margin, in a Linear layout?

Comment: Added my code which didn't work. What do you suggest?