# LinearLayout android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" works at design time but doesn't at run time

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dice_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/empty_dice"
        tools:src="@drawable/dice_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/roll_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/roll" />

</LinearLayout>
```

on design time i got the linearlayout centered verticaly , but when i test it on emulator or my device the linear layout is displayed at the top of the screen

[image: Design Time]

[image: Run Time]

Comment: Why don't you go with RelativeLayout and use `centerInParent = true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your LinearLayout, change `layout_gravity` to just `gravity`

Comment: thanks Mike , but why there is no sync between the design and run time ?

Answer (score 2):

**Don't**

```
 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

You should use  [**`android:gravity="center_vertical"`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity#CENTER_VERTICAL)

> Place object in the vertical center of its container, not changing its
>   size

Comment: android:gravity sets the gravity of the contents (i.e. its subviews) of the View it's used on.
android:layout_gravity sets the gravity of the View or Layout relative to its parent. so that is not true ???!!!

Comment: @Sh.Raai exactly.

Comment: @Sh.Raai read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/what-is-the-difference-between-gravity-and-layout-gravity-in-android

Answer (score 0):

In the layout:

change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

to

`android:layout_height="match_parent"`