# How to align Text to Top, Bottom and Center Vertically in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout, android-compose-layout

How can I align the text using `Text` composable function vertically. Is there a way to do it without having to add another extra view to contain the `Text`.

The `textAlign` parameter of `Text` only has the following options:

`TextAlign.`

- Left
- Right
- Center
- Justify
- Start
- End

I have tried using `textAlign = TextAlign.Center` but it only centers it horizontally. How can I center it vertically without wrapping it in another view?

```
Text(
    text = "Text",
    modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp),
    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
)
```

**Result:**

[image: result]

**What I am trying to achieve:**

[image: what I am trying to achieve]

Comment: Post your code and an image of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: no, you can't do that without a container.

Comment: Gabriele Mariotti, I edited the question

Comment: Philip Dukhov, ah okay thank you, so my only choice now is to wrap it in another view, for example a ```Box```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have to use a **parent container** and align the composable inside it.

For example a **`Box`**:

```
Box( 
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentAlignment = Center
) {
    Text(
        text = "Text",
    )
}
```

or a **`Column`**:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    Text(
        text = "Text",
    )
}
```

Comment: "Type mismatch.
Required:
Alignment.Horizontal
Found:
Arrangement.HorizontalOrVertical"

Comment: `VerticalArrangement` doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky The `verticalArrangement` defines the vertical arrangement of the layout's children in the `Column`. Check also the height of the parent container.

Answer (score 11):

first use `.wrapContentHeight()` in modifier, then you can use `align(CenterVertically)` param to center the text.

Answer (score 6):

It is difficult to give an exact answer without seeing your code, but I would say you need to use container's `Alignment.CenterVertically` instead of `TextAlign`

Something like:

```
Row {
    Text(
        text = "Text",
        modifier = Modifier.align(alignment = Alignment.CenterVertically)
    )

    Image(
        ...
    )
}
```

or:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
) {
    Text(text = "Text")
    Text(text = "Text 2")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66303328/jetpack-compose-how-to-align-text-to-bottom-left-or-right) which is done with `android:gravity` param using views, as answered by PhilipDukhov it's not possible only with `Text`, you need to have another container, preferably `Box` to align `Text` component inside.

Answer (score 1):

Create a simple composable function to show anything in center:

```
@Composable
fun Center(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier,
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

Call it from any other function:

```
@Composable
fun CenterAlignedText() {
    Center(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text("Hello World!")
    }
}
```