# Align a composable view to right side inside a Row Composable like alignParentRight

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm building a custom composable function view inside which I used Row composable, however I want to align the right icon to right end of the Row(align to the end of the parent)

below is my code:

```
    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .wrapContentHeight()
        .padding(vertical = Spacing30),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
    
    Icon(modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 14.dp), painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_wallet),
         contentDescription
         = "limit_type")
        
    Text(text = "₹10,000", style = Typography.TitleSecondary.copy(color = ContentPrimary))
   
    Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_chevron_right),
         contentDescription
         = "chevron_right")
}
```

In Constrained layout I could have used `ConstrainedEndToEndOf = parent`
In RelativeLayout I could have used `alignParentRight = true`

However, I want to use Row composable only, since there are more complex composable inside it.

I have used Box composable earlier in which it is very straight forward with the modifier, as explained in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66310192/4961126), however with the `Row` and `Column`(align to bottom) it seems to be difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it by using the `Spacer` with `weight` modifier.

```
Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
```

By adding a Spacer with weight 1f just before the view that I want to align to the end solved my problem below is my code.

```
    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .wrapContentHeight()
        .padding(vertical = Spacing30),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
    
    Icon(modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 14.dp), painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_wallet),
         contentDescription
         = "limit_type")

        Text(text = "₹10,000", style = Typography.TitleSecondary.copy(color = ContentPrimary))

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
    
    Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_chevron_right),
         contentDescription
         = "chevron_right")
}
```

The good part is this works for both the Row and Column, if in the Column we want to align a view to the bottom we can simply add `Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))` just before the view that we want to align to the bottom or to the right(in case of `Row` composable)