# Difference in behavior of android:gravity="center_vertical" for RelativeLayout and LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Let's say I have two views that I want to center vertically. The first view is bigger than the second view.

I noticed that if I place theses two views inside a `RelativeLayout` with properties `layout_height="wrap_content"` and `android:gravity="center_vertical"` nothing happens. This is what I get :

[image]

In the opposite, if I place these two views inside a `LinearLayour` with properties `layout_height="wrap_content"` and `android:gravity="center_vertical"` the views are centered vertically :

[image]

Lastly, if I place these two views inside a `RelativeLayout` with properties `layout_height` with a fixed height and `android:gravity="center_vertical"` I get the same result as the `LinearLayout`. The views are centered vertically.

I would expect the views to be centered vertically in each case. Do you know the reason for this difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android relative layout problem with gravity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804411/android-relative-layout-problem-with-gravity)

Answer (score 1):

LinearLayout handles all its child object based on its orientation (Horizontal or vertical). So when you are saying gravity: "center_vertical". You are actually referencing based on your parent layout.

In case of RelativeLayout,it enables you to specify the location of child objects relative to each other (child A to the left of child B) or to the parent (aligned to the top of the parent).

Personally I would use gravity only in LinearLayouts and the centerInParent for RelativeLayouts.

Answer (score 0):

In your first case it'll work with `RelativeLayout` as you expected if you use `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to the child view which you want to be centred.

So in case of `LinearLayout` you need to specify the `orientation` first (i.e. horizontal/vertical) so that the child views are inflated based on the reference of your parent layout.

While in `RelativeLayout`, as the name says it all, you can specify the position with respect to the views which are the child of a parent `RelativeLayout`.

Now the views you want to achieve can be generated in many other ways too.

For example, set your parent layout as `LinearLayout`. Don't specify any `gravity` attribute in the parent layout. Hence, you set a `layout_gravity` attribute to the child to `certer_vertical`  and this should work too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some others tests, it seems that the behavior of `android:gravity` for a `RelativeLayout` is a bit random. I will just avoid to use is.