# Why doesn't gravity work when applied to Relative Layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I already understand that if I use `layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` on the text view, then the text will be center. But I don't want to use that because I want to have as little code as possible and the best way to do that is by applying `gravity="center_horizontal"` to my relative layout. I am also asking this question because I am concerned about even using `gravity` or `layout_gravity` with relative layouts at all. As when doing my research I came upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26190050/1304252) answer.

Notice the part that says:

> Don't use gravity/layout_gravity with a RelativeLayout. Use them for Views in LinearLayouts and FrameLayouts.

Even though it seems pretty apparent to me from the relative layout [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#attr_android:gravity), which clearly lists `gravity` as a valid attribute, that Google intended these attributes to be used with relative layouts.

If that quote is correct, how do I center views in relative layouts?

Also, here is my code:

Notice the title is not centered horizontally

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context="com.something">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/app_title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/main_spacing"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/enterContact"
        android:text="Enter Contact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/main_spacing" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a supplemental answer to [Gravity and layout_gravity on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26190050/3681880).

## View `gravity` and `layout_gravity` inside a Relative Layout

My original statement that `gravity` and `layout_gravity` should not be used in the subviews of a `RelativeLayout` was partly wrong. The `gravity` actually works fine. However, `layout_gravity` has no effect. This can be seen in the example below. The light green and light blue are TextViews. The other two background colors are RelativeLayouts.

[image]

As you can see, `gravity` works, but `layout_gravity` doesn't work.

## Relative Layout with `gravity`

My [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26190050/3681880) about `gravity` and `layout_gravity` dealt with these attributes being applied to the Views within a `ViewGroup` (specifically a `LinearLayout`), not to the `ViewGroup` itself. However, it is possible to set `gravity` and `layout_gravity` on a `RelativeLayout`. The `layout_gravity` would affect how the `RelativeLayout` is positioned within its own parent, so I will not deal with that here. How `gravity` affects the subviews, though, is shown in the image below.

[image]

I resized the widths of all the subviews so that what is happening is more clear. Note that the way `RelativeLayout` handles gravity is to take all the subviews as a group and move them around the layout. This means that whichever view is widest will determine how everything else is positioned. So gravity in a Relative layout is probably only useful if all the subviews have the same width.

## Linear Layout with `gravity`

When you add `gravity` to a `LinearLayout`, it does arrange the subviews as one would expect. For example, one could "save code" by setting the `gravity` of `LinearLayout` to `center_horizontally`. That way there is no need individually set the `layout_gravity` of each subview. See the various options in the image below.

[image]

Note that when a view uses `layout_gravity`, it overrides the LinearLayout's gravity. (This can be seen in the title for the two layouts in the left image. The LinearLayout `gravity` was set to `left` and `right`, but the title TextView's `layout_gravity` was set to `center_horizontally`.)

## Final notes

When [positioning views within a RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html#Position), the general way to do it is adding things like the following to *each* view:

- `layout_alignParentTop`
- `layout_centerVertical`
- `layout_below`
- `layout_toRightOf`

If one wants to set all the views at once, a `LinearLayout` would likely be better (or perhaps using a Style).

So to sum up,

- The `layout_gravity` does not work for subviews in a RelativeLayout.
- The `gravity` of a RelativeLayout does work, but not as one might expect.

## Supplemental XML

XML for image **"View `gravity` and `layout_gravity` inside a Relative Layout"**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#e3e2ad" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTop1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="Views' gravity=" />

        <!-- examples of gravity -->
        
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTop2"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvTop1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#bcf5b1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="left" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTop3"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvTop2"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#aacaff"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTop4"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvTop3"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#bcf5b1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="right" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTop5"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvTop4"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#aacaff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="center" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#d6c6cd" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBottom1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="Views' layout_gravity=" />

        <!-- examples of layout_gravity -->
        
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBottom2"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvBottom1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="#bcf5b1"
            android:text="left" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBottom3"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvBottom2"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#aacaff"
            android:text="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBottom4"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvBottom3"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="#bcf5b1"
            android:text="right" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBottom5"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvBottom4"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#aacaff"
            android:text="center" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

XML for image **"Relative Layout with gravity"**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#e3e2ad" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTop1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="Views' gravity=" />

        <!-- examples of gravity -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTop2"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvTop1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#bcf5b1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="left" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTop3"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvTop2"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#aacaff"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTop4"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvTop3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#bcf5b1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="right" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTop5"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvTop4"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#aacaff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="center" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#d6c6cd" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBottom1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="Views' gravity=" />

        <!-- examples of layout_gravity -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBottom2"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvBottom1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:background="#bcf5b1"
            android:text="left" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBottom3"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvBottom2"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#aacaff"
            android:text="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBottom4"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvBottom3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:background="#bcf5b1"
            android:text="right" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBottom5"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvBottom4"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#aacaff"
            android:text="center" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

XML for image **"Linear Layout with gravity"**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#e3e2ad"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="View's gravity=" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#bcf5b1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="left" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#aacaff"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#bcf5b1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="right" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#aacaff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#d6c6cd"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="View's gravity=" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#bcf5b1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="left" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#aacaff"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#bcf5b1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="right" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#aacaff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing your layout, for me it's working (the `TextView` is centered correctly).

However, you could also remove `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` from the `RelativeLayout` and add `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` in the `TextView`.

Comment: hmm, it's working for you? I just tested on my phone and it's not working. It looks like what the last image I posted is showing, where the left side of the title is lined up with the left side of the parent.

Comment: Okay the problem is when I have the autocompletetextview as a child of the relative layout. For whatever reason that kills the gravity setting. I added more code that actually doesn't work this time.

Comment: Testing with the `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` property into the TextView, it's working fine

Comment: yeah, I mean I appreciate your help. I was just seeing if I could figure out why I can't just apply 1 line of code to all the children in the relative layout (i.e. gravity on relative layout) and have everything be center but it's just not working out for me and I guess I just have to accept the fact that android layout design is super glitchy.

Comment: Yes, in this specific case I don't know why it's not working

Comment: Note however that if you put some TextView's one below the other (not AutocompleteTextView), the gravity in the RelativeLayout works.

Comment: Note also, that if you set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to the AutoCompleteTextView, the gravity works!! So it's a very specifi problem of the AutoCompleteTextView and `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Comment: you're right, but gravity still only works with the top item, the rest of the items are left aligned with the left side of the top item :P

Comment: I mean: if you remove the AutoCompleteTextView, and put other TextViews one below the other, gravity setted on the RelativeLayout level, works on all the TextViews (just tested)

Comment: so it seems to only work with textviews, anything else like a button or switch, etc. does that left align thing

Comment: Well, actually it works on all the components except of AutoCompleteTextView (with `android:layout_width="match_parent`). You can try to test with the other components, it should work. Actually, what I guess is that it works on all the components (also with AutoCompleteTextView), under the condition that all have setted `android:layout_width="wrap_content`.

Comment: Hey Valentino, just wanted to let you know a good accepted answer was posted to this question in case you're interested. The important point to know is: "whichever view is widest will determine how everything else is positioned".

Comment: Thanks so much! I appreciate a lot :) I will read it as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

I've always had problems with RelativeLayouts and TextViews too. I think that this is due to the fact that TextView calculates its size dynamically and this prevents it to work well with layout's gravity. That's just one my supposition.
The solution I generally adopt is to configure a textview horizontal size with match_parent. It might be a suboptimal solution, but should work. In case you need a Fixed size textView you can put a fixed size dimension and should work too, it gives problems only with wrap_content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context="com.something">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/app_title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/main_spacing"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit:
as suggested by @Valentino S., adding

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

with wrap_content should work too. The reason is in my head still the same: size of textView is calculated later.

Comment: hey, I appreciate your answer but also I edited my code since the stripped down code I added actually was working. It seems that the code gravity gets messed up when I add a autocompletetextview as a child to the relative layout. any thoughts about that?

Comment: LOL :) not really... anyway, keep it as an alternative way, if it's not a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:text="TITLE"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/enterContact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:text="Enter Contact"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: You just changed 'android:layout_width' of the textview to match_parent. This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: `see how in the last image the title is to the left`  the title is now in center of the layout..so what is ur question?

Comment: The box surrounding the title is the outline of the textview, it should be center in the relative layout. Sorry, I see why that was confusing.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation says](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#attr_android:gravity):

> **android:gravity**
>
> Specifies how an object should position its content, on both the X and
>   Y axes, within its own bounds.
>
> ...
>
> `center_horizontal`
>
> Place object in the horizontal center of its container, not changing
>   its size.

So the `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` will center horizontal-ing the RelativeLayout to its parent. Not making its content center horizontal.

Remember that `android:layout_gravity` is used for the view itself relative to the parent or layout.

Please be aware that the behaviour of Layout can differ slightly for each API Level. And be noted, that we can't 100% sure that the visual result in Layout Editor is correct. Always test your layout in real devices.

Comment: from your link, **Specifies how an object should position its content, on both the X and Y axes, within its own bounds.**, I think you missread it :)

Comment: I understood the documentation correctly. Also, I tested on my device and the layout editor seems to match the actual result on my device in this particular case.

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley: some text below the linked text.. Not found an anchor for it in the documentation :P

Comment: @ImpalaTamer: You need to test it with new API Level. I've experience some of the anomalies with layout when upgrading my sdk build version.

Comment: not 100% sure, but i think the text about *center_horizontal* refers to the generic meaning of this keyword. The useful part should be the *gravity* description, but I can fail :)

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך I am testing on API 25 which is the latest.

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley: Well, you're right. The quoted text give ambiguous. I've update it.

Comment: @ImpalaTamer: Looks like I've misunderstood your question. I'm sorry for that, late night here. Answering your question, you need to use `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` for each view or you can try adding another RelativeLayout inside the RelativeLayout with `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`

Answer (score 0):

TlDr:   android:gravity **Works** with RelativeLayout  , you can skip to the bottom if you don't want to read the explanation

EDIT this is a giant wall of text, please bear with me

This is what I imagine you want to achieve:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/app_title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/main_spacing"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>  <!-- LAYOUT PARAMS WORK!!!-->
```

Why does this work, while `android:gravity` (*apparently*) doesn't?

1. if your goal is to put the TextView in the horizontal center of the Layout/Screen you have to let the `RelativeLayout` know!
2. this is achieved through something called `LayoutParams` - these are data structures defined by each `View` which are used by the View's parent (in this case the RelativeLayout)
3. so let's say your `TextView` has the following `LayoutParams` :

   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

you will get something like this:

[image]

When the `RelativeLayout` is distributing its child views around the screen, along the way there is a callback method being run - [onLayout(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onLayout(boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) - which is part of a more complex method sequence that ***will determine the position of each child View inside the RelativeLayout***, this is achieved in part by accessing the `LayoutParams` in each child `View`, in this case that line in your `TextView`

4. This is why we say LayoutParams are passed on to the parent like in the [link you mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26190050/2819928)

**WARNING**: Endless Confusion Source!

View positioning inside `Layout`s / `ViewGroup`s is done through `LayoutParam`s the `onLayout` calls

It so happens that some layouts like `FrameLayout` have a LayoutParam called [android:layout_gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html) which causes great confusion with the `android:gravity` property that each view can define, which is **NOT the same** and not even a `LayoutParam`

`android:gravity` is used by any View (like a `TextView` for example) to place its content inside.

Example: let's say that you change your **TextView** to be **very high**, and you want the text at the bottom of the TextView, instead of at the top

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="95dp"   <------------ very high!
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/app_title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/main_spacing"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" <----- LayoutParams for RelativeLayout
        />
```

[image: TextView is CENTERED but text is at the TOP]

TextView is **CENTERED in the RelativeLayout** but text is at the **TOP of the "box"**

Let's use android:gravity to manage the *text position* **INSIDE THE `TextView`**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/app_title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/main_spacing"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"       <---**NOT LayoutParams**, NOT passed to RLayout
        />
```

Result: As expected only the **inside** of the View changed

[image]

TLDR
Now if you want to ignore everything above and still use android:gravity with RelativeLayout, `RelativeLayout` **is** also a `View`so it has the android:gravity property, but you have to **remove** other properties or LayoutParams which will **override the behaviour** defined by the android:gravity property look at android:gravity at work with `RelativeLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:gravity="bottom">   <!-- NOT LAYOUT PARAMS -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/app_title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/main_spacing"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/enterContact"
        android:text="Enter Contact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/main_spacing" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: `gravity` is not a LayoutParams because `gravity`, in a Relative Layout, is not meant to be used to tell a Relative Layout's parent some information. It is meant to tell the Relative Layout's children how they should be aligned within in the Relative Layout. This is why the attribute, `gravity`, exists in [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#attr_android:gravity) Relative Layout documentation. `gravity` applied to a Frame Layout works in the exact opposite fashion as `gravity` applied to a Relative Layout and the documentation accurately shows that.

Comment: @ImpalaTamer yes indeed, as I was saying, android:layout_gravity is a LayoutParam, and is passed to the parent ViewGroup in the hierarchy, android:gravity is used within the View itself - not passed to the parent, also no mention of LayoutParams here ;)

Comment: yeah so in my question, I'm having problems with `gravity` applied to a Relative Layout. Any thoughts on the glitches I'm having?

Comment: @ImpalaTamer Alright i was under the impression you had solved the issue and were trying to understand the reason behind it let me have a look at your xml and try to help after dinner

Comment: well I actually have a solution that I can move forward with but I really would like to know why `gravity` doesn't work with Relative Layouts so if you have any ideas about that, that would be cool and that's the answer I would consider the "best".

Comment: @ImpalaTamer I have written an in depth explanation, with examples, I hope it helps you understand, take a look at the edited answer. Spoiler: android:gravity works with RelativeLayout,  you just shouldnt use it because you have so much better/versatile tools  with the RelativeLayout  LayoutParams. Cheers!

Comment: @ImpalaTamer did you understand the explanation?

Comment: I understand your explanation but it doesn't really answer my question as to why gravity of a relative layout wasn't doing what I expected it to do. There is an answer here that says "whichever view is widest will determine how everything else is positioned. So gravity in a Relative layout is probably only useful if all the subviews have the same width." That's what I needed to know to clear my confusion. I really appreciate your effort though.